# How to grant execute on dbms_lock in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, privileges

I need to use dbms_lock.sleep procedure from user usr1. I can't login as sys, but I have a password for user usr2 which have "grant any object privilege" privilege. However, when I'm logged in as usr2 and try to issue

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_lock to usr1
```

I get the ORA-01031 "insufficient privileges" exception. The same works with a test package on another user. Are the system packages treated specially, or have I missed something?

Comment: Oracle have [promised to fix this in a future release by adding a `sleep` procedure to `dbms_session`](https://community.oracle.com/ideas/4852).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The system packages are treated specially, depending on the value of the initialisation parameter `O7_DICTIONARY_ACCESSIBILITY`. If that is `FALSE`, which is the default since Oracle 9i, then `ANY` privileges don't apply to the data dictionary. The documentation refers to this as 'dictionary protection'.

The closest I can find in the security guide - [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/authorization.htm#BABHIFHF) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/guidelines.htm#i1007433) - only refer to tables as examples.

Oracle Support note 174753.1, however, explicitly states that dictionary protection supersedes `grant any object privilege`. I'm not allowed to quote that but it explains what you're seeing; it might be worth looking up if you have access to it.

So, the only way for `usr2` to be able to `grant execute on sys.dbms_lock to usr1` is for the DBA to have done `grant execute on sys.dbms_lock to usr2 with grant option`.

As Ben says, you'll have to either get the DBA to grant the permission to `usr1` directly, or add the `with grant option` to the privileges granted to `usr2`; or have `usr2` create a wrapper procedure around the `dbms_lock` call and grant permissions on that to `usr1`.

Comment: Just stumbled upon [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2564566/266304) which shows a wrapper around `dbms_lock`.

Answer (score 4):

It *sounds* as though SYS hasn't been granted the DBA role or that SYS doesn't have the GRANT ANY OBJECT privilege. To quote from [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9013.htm#i2094944)

> To grant an object privilege, you must own the object, or the owner of
>   the object must have granted you the object privileges with the GRANT
>   OPTION, or you must have been granted the GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE
>   system privilege. If you have the GRANT ANY OBJECT PRIVILEGE, then you
>   can grant the object privilege only if the object owner could have
>   granted the same object privilege.

This implies that you can't grant execute on `dbms_lock` because SYS wouldn't have been able to do so.

On installation [SYS is automatically granted the DBA role](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dba005.htm#ADMIN11045) so maybe someone's been changing this or created another user with the DBA role.

Either way you're going to have to get your DBA involved if you only have access to these two users. Ask them to grant execute on the packages you need to the users that need it. It's up to them to give you a good reason why they won't grant you execute on the packages you need in order to do your job.

If you can't get full access to `dbms_lock` you can always create a procedure in another user that wraps `dbms_lock.sleep` you need and then grant execute on that procedure alone.

Comment: I see the same thing (11gR2); but `SYS` can definitely grant execute on `dbms_lock`, and apparently has to grant it to `usr2` or that gets an unknown table error rather than insufficient privileges. The same thing happens with other packages, not just that one. Although I haven't found it documented anywhere yet, it does seem like `SYS` objects have another layer of protection; which I guess isn't entirely unreasonable. Interesting.

Comment: I'll check what you say, but I think a user can always grant execute on his own package to anyone, can't he?

Comment: sorry, but this answer is completely wrong. If `grant execute on sys.dbms_lock to usr1` it does not sound that SYS has a problem, but that user usr1 has a problem. So your assumptions are false and therefore the conclusions useless. In the [other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13414574/754550) it is explained that this is the expected behavior of the database.