# Introduction of Sleep time using DBMS_LOCK.sleep(time in seconds) in stored procedure in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I want to introduce sleep time for my already stored procedure. Can you please let me know the syntax for that like where to place it in my procedure.
I want to use DBMS_LOCK.sleep(time in seconds).

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help center]. You can also read about [ask] a good question.

Comment: Hope this link help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561671/sleep-function-in-oracle

Comment: No Trushna, that is not giving me the information required.

Comment: This is the [official oracle 12c doc on dbms_lock.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66782).

Comment: If you can provide the code snippet it will be easy for us to comment/answer

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly you need the implementation of dbms_lock.sleep in your procedure.
Basic idea of SLEEP Procedure is snooze the logic for mentioned seconds. so you can refer below snippet. Hope it helps.

```
BEGIN
  FOR I IN (
  /*YOUR SELECT QUERY */
  )
  LOOP
    --Your processing logic
    dbms_lock.SLEEP(10);
  END LOOP;
END;
```