# Oracle SQL select statement which "sleeps"? Plain SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a generic SQL select statement executor with "Groovy-SQL" (=Java JDBC Wrapper). It has got a timeout feature.

To test the timeout feature in an automated integration test I'd like to issue a SQL select like

```
SELECT sleep(10) from DUAL;
```

which should run for 10 seconds and then return. Like MySql's http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_sleep.

Is there something like this also in Oracle to simulate a "long running" query? I'd like to have a **plain SQL query**, without any PL/SQL or special grants like in the [Sleep function in ORACLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561671/sleep-function-in-oracle) discussion.

Comment: I can think of one terrible thing: try to find a regular expression that triggers catastrophic backtracking and use it in a `REGEXP_LIKE`. You won't be able to regulate the timeout, and your DBA is going to hate you if you succeed, but it *would* be SQL only...

Comment: Very ugly but very cool idea @JeroenMostert!

Comment: Please, *please* don't use that on a production system though. The resulting CPU spike would not be pretty. (I assume Oracle has a way of shooting runaway threads, but I have no experience.)

Comment: Sure, @JeroenMostert. I would issue it on a test instance and abort the statement after let's say 1 second. The interesting part here will be if Oracle can internally really kill (interrupt) the slow regex.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dbms_lock.sleep()`

```
begin
   dbms_lock.sleep(10);
end;
```

This can be execute JDBC if you pass the whole PL/SQL block as a single string:

```
String sleep = "begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); end;";
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sleep);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lock.htm#ARPLS66782

This does however call a PL/SQL procedure so it doesn't really qualify as "without stored functions".

Comment: This will work only if he can grant access on `dbms_lock`

Comment: `dbms_lock.sleep` is procedure not function so you can't use it from SQL like this.

Comment: @Husqvik: a right. I always forget that

Comment: I have no grant for dbms_lock :-(. Isn't there something "pure sql-ish"?

Comment: @Peti: that **is** "pure" SQL-ish (at least as pure as it gets)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, "begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); end;" is SQL?

Comment: It worked for me  using hibernate also `entityManager.createNativeQuery("begin dbms_lock.sleep(10); end;").executeUpdate()`