# How do I comment on the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, comments

In Bash, # is used to comment the following. How do I make a comment on the Windows command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which comment style should I use in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407800/which-comment-style-should-i-use-in-batch-files)

Comment: For block comments see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526946/commenting-multiple-lines-in-dos-batch-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "comment-out" (add comment) in a batch/cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269338/how-to-comment-out-add-comment-in-a-batch-cmd)

Answer (score 264, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `rem`, short for "remark".

There is also a shorthand version `::` that some people use, and this *sort of* looks like `#` if you squint a bit and look at it sideways. I originally preferred that variant since I'm a `bash`-aholic and I'm still trying to forget the painful days of BASIC :-)

Unfortunately, there are situations where `::` stuffs up the command line processor (such as within complex `if` or `for` statements) so I generally use `rem` nowadays. In any case, it's a hack, suborning the label infrastructure to make it *look* like a comment when it really isn't. For example, try replacing `rem` with `::` in the following example and see how it works out:

```
if 1==1 (
    rem comment line 1
    echo 1 equals 1
    rem comment line 2
)
```

You should also keep in mind that `rem` is a *command,* so you can't just bang it at the end of a line like the `#` in `bash`. It has to go where a command would go. For example, the first line below outputs all `hello rem a comment` but the second outputs the single word `hello`:

```
echo hello rem a comment.
echo hello& rem a comment.
```

The second is two *separate* commands separated by `&`, and with no spaces before the `&` because echo will output those as well. That's not necessarily important for screen output but, if you're redirecting to a file, it may:

```
echo hello >file          - includes the space.
echo hello>file           - no space.
```

Comment: I knew of REM but was not aware of the `::` syntax. Is it not widely known?

Comment: Well, I know there's one person that knew of it. And now there's two :-) Maybe I can claim that I doubled the amount of knowledge in the world. FWIW, Rob van der Woude's site is a truly excellent one for batch file (and other) chicanery: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php

Comment: [Which comment style should I use in batch files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12407800/395857) gives more details about `::`.

Comment: To avoid the comment from appearing in the output you can prefix `REM` with an `@`: `@REM Some comment`

Comment: @david-rogers [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29853831/5478086) seems more appropriate since it allows comments in the command line.

Comment: @Herman: Though I already had the use of `&` in the answer (as `rem` is a command), I've expanded on the explanation.

Answer (score 37):

Sometimes, it is convenient to add a comment to a command line. For that, you can use "&REM misc comment text" or, now that I know about it, "&:: misc comment text". For example:

```
REM SET Token="4C6F72656D20697073756D20646F6C6F" &REM This token is for localhost
SET Token="722073697420616D65742C20636F6E73" &REM This token is for production
```

This makes it easy to keep track of multiple sets of values when doing exploration, tests of concept, etc. This approach works because '&' introduces a new command on the same line.

Answer (score 31):

A comment is produced using the REM command which is short for "Remark".

```
REM Comment here...
```

Answer (score 21):

```
: this is one way to comment
```

As a result:

```
:: this will also work
:; so will this
:! and this
: ***** and so on ***** :
: // even this \\ :
```

Above styles work **outside** codeblocks, otherwise:

```
REM is another way to comment.
```

Answer (score 20):

It's "REM".

Example:

```
REM This is a comment
```

Answer (score 9):

Lines starting with "rem" (from the word remarks) are comments:

```
rem comment here
echo "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Powershell

For powershell, use `#`:

```
PS C:\> echo foo # This is a comment
foo
```

Answer (score 0):

1. A single colon without a space after it is enough
2. Just don't leave comments at the last line in block

Finally, this works:

```
if 1==1 (
    :comment line 1
    echo 1 equals 1
)
```