# Code block comment syntax in Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax, comments

Is there any syntax for multi-line code block comment in Windows batch script? I know `REM` and `::` for line-by-line comment, but it is not efficient to comment a code block.

I'm looking for the block comment style like something below in PHP:

```
/*
This is multi-lines
block comment
*/
```

Comment: is this what you were looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526946/commenting-multiple-lines-in-dos-batch-file

Comment: Indeed... marking as duplicate..

Answer (score 2):

I think, this can serve the purpose

```
goto:skip1
echo This line should not get executed
format c: & echo nor this line
:skip1
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this trick that looks better...

```
@echo off
setlocal

set comment=goto endcomment

echo This line is executed

%comment%
echo These lines
echo are commented out...
:endcomment

echo The next line to execute

%comment%
You may place here
  %$#"#% anything you want.... &!>|<()
:endcomment

echo End of example
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in batch scripts.

(gotos excluded...)

Answer (score 0):

Multiline comment without those nasty `goto`s, `rem`s and `::`

```
@break || (
 1 line
 2 line
 3 line
 4 line
 5 line
 ...
)
```

**EDIT**: As the previous example is not working, you can create a macro

```
set "[:=goto :]%%"
set "[=rem/||(" & set "]=)"
```

```
%[:%
  multiline
  comment
%:]%
```

(Not works in the for loop)

Comment: How is this supposed to work? What does @break normally do? (Also, this syntax didn't work for me in a batch file. It still executed the excluded lines)

Comment: @gamingexpert13 Sets or clears extended CTRL+C checking on MS-DOS systems. If used without parameters, break displays the existing setting value.

If command extensions are enabled and running on the Windows platform, inserting the break command into a batch file enters a hard-coded breakpoint if being debugged by a debugger. Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/break