# Batch GOTO label with duplicate labels

Tags: batch-file, label, goto

I unfortunately own a batch program that has duplicate label names. Can anyone explain why the GOTO goes to the label in the second block, not the first?
The code:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET FLAG=1
IF [%FLAG%]==[1] (
    ECHO IN THE FIRST IF...
    GOTO TD_NEXT
:TD_NEXT
    ECHO HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE FIRST BLOCK
)

IF [%FLAG%]==[1] (
    ECHO IN THE SECOND IF...
    GOTO TD_NEXT
:TD_NEXT
     ECHO HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE SECOND BLOCK
)
```

The output:

```
IN THE FIRST IF...
HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE SECOND BLOCK
```

I can add a third block, and see that it jumps to the one after the next, each time.

```
IN THE FIRST IF...
HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE SECOND BLOCK
IN THE THIRD IF...
HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE FIRST BLOCK
IN THE SECOND IF...
HERE AT TD_NEXT IN THE THIRD BLOCK
```

Answer (score 5):

Interesting problem! The answer is comprised of two parts:

1- A `goto` command always seek for the label from *the next instruction* to the end of the file. If the label is not found, the seek is restarted from the beginning of the file up to the same line of the original `goto` command. If not found, an error is issued.

2- In previous description, the *next instruction* usually refers to the line following the `goto`. However, if the `goto` is placed *inside a code block* (that should never be done, but that is another story), then the "current instruction" is the whole code block where the `goto` is placed. This means that the label is seek *from the end of the `if` command* on...

This is just another reason to *not* place labels inside code blocks; this also cause several other problems.

**EDIT**: See this funny example:

```
@echo off

set var=1
if %var% equ 1 (

:NEXT
   if %var% neq 1 goto NEXT
   echo This appear first time:  var=%var%
   set var=2
   goto NEXT

:NEXT
   echo This appear second time: var=%var%

)
```

Output:

```
This appear first time:  var=1
This appear second time: var=2
```

**SECOND EDIT**: The example below proves that the labels are seek in the way described at point 1 above:

```
@echo off

goto PATCH

:LABEL
echo :LABEL >> "%~F0"
echo echo At end of file >> "%~F0"

:PATCH
echo In an infinite loop:
goto LABEL
```

Output:

```
In an infinite loop:
In an infinite loop:
At end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is that the *last* label by that name is the one that the interpreter remembers. The interpreter stores labels and locations in a table in memory. If it comes across another label with the same name, this simply overwrites the previous label with the same name.

Cheers