# How to "comment-out" (add comment) in a batch/cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, comments, comment-conventions

I have a batch file that runs several python scripts that do table modifications.

1. I want to have users comment out the 1-2 python scripts that they don't want to run, rather than removing them from the batch file (so the next user knows these scripts exist as options!)
2. I also want to add comments to bring to their attention specifically the variables they need to update in the Batch file before they run it. I see that I can use `REM`. But it looks like that's more for updating the user with progress after they've run it.

Is there a syntax for more appropriately adding a comment?

Comment: See also excellent answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/12407800/1011025

Comment: You can Use `Rem Sth` Command Or Use This Mark : `::  Sth`

Comment: I prefer to use:
- REM for comments
- &REM for inline comments

Answer (score 995, accepted):

The `rem` command is indeed for comments. It doesn't inherently update anyone after running the script. Some script authors might use it that way instead of `echo`, though, because by default the batch interpreter will *print out* each command before it's processed. Since `rem` commands don't do anything, it's safe to print them without side effects. To avoid printing a command, prefix it with `@`, or, to apply that setting throughout the program, run `@echo off`. (It's `echo off` to avoid printing further commands; the `@` is to avoid printing *that* command prior to the echo setting taking effect.)

So, in your batch file, you might use this:

```
@echo off
REM To skip the following Python commands, put "REM" before them:
python foo.py
python bar.py
```

Comment: you can also use two colons "::". It is one of two ways of adding remarks into the batch file without displaying or executing that line when the batch file is run. Unlike REM this line will not show regardless if ECHO off is in the batch file.

Comment: @Brent81 I feel this should be the correct answer. When using syntax highlighting the REM command does not actually highlight the text as "commented out".

Comment: The double-colon is an "invalid label"; here's an article that explains it, and why it's performance may be better than REM (especially on floppy disks!), and it won't work in indented code blocks (only on the first character): http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php

Comment: Interesting. I though REM was the 'whole line comment' and the double colon was the 'inline comment', like
`REM This whole line is a comment`
`@echo off   :: This comment is inline`

Comment: @Alhadis, Perl's Configure script is written in Bourne shell, not Windows batch, so how is it relevant here? Furthermore, the colon command being valid Bourne syntax is not a "bonus side effect"; it's precisely _why_ it's used in that _Bourne script_. It's used in favor of `#` for comments because `#`, evidently, might not be a valid comment designator in _all_ the shells Configure is intended to support; see line 3.

Comment: @RobKennedy I was high when I wrote that, please ignore

Comment: @Richard Smith, I get an error running `echo off & :: TEST`. Even when putting an `@` in front of `echo`, it still seems to give the same error which is, `echo was unexpected at this time.` Is there a way to comment after `echo off` (inline comment in other words)?

Comment: @BillJoe Add a blank newline after `@echo off &  ::This is a comment` and it works. echo behaves strangely sometimes.

Answer (score 1298):

## Use `::` or `REM`

```
::   commenttttttttttt
REM  commenttttttttttt
```

## BUT (as people noted):

- if they are not in the beginning of line, then add `&` character:
  `your commands here      & ::  commenttttttttttt`
- Inside nested parts (`IF/ELSE`, `FOR` loops, etc...) `::` should be followed with normal line, otherwise it gives error (use `REM` there).
- `::` may also fail within `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`

Comment: The double colon :: Is the cleanest .bat comment there is. And it can be used at the start or middle of a line!

Comment: Didn't work for me when done inline like this.    `cd "C:\Folder" ::this throws a syntax error`

Comment: Also fails in `git add :: blah this is not a comment` with "fatal: pathspec 'blah' did not match any files"

Comment: this is meant for **`cmd`** mainly.. i dont know if it works for other software (except **command prompt**)..

Comment: This should be the answer - +1

Comment: For a comment on the same line as the example illustrates, you need to add `&` between the code and the comment `::`. To illustrate, open cmd prompt and run `dir ::blah` which doesn't list the contents of `.` and compare with `dir & ::blah`, which does

Comment: @Rado this is essential! If you don't know it, `::`-comments will produce an error. Thus, I am using `rem` instead which seemingly doesn't need a `&`

Comment: Thankd @tazotodua The double colon :: Is the cleanest .bat comment there is. And it can be used at the start or middle of a line!

Comment: Warning, using `::` will bug scripts with `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `for`

Comment: The double colon can also cause problems inside an IF block. Problems like ') was unexpected at this time', or 'The system cannot find the drive specified.'

Comment: [Examples](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php) of how using `::` labels as comments can cause difficult-to-anticipate errors. Calling this clean is a bit misleading @ATSiem

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett  btw, seems this question to be old than another. so which one you mean in duplicate?

Comment: @T.Todua Doesn't really matter which is older or newer. They both ask about pretty much the same thing, and get very similar answers. So the one should be closed as duplicate of the other. The other one, though, has an accepted answer that is better than this one's accepted answer, so I think this one should be closed and point to the other.

Comment: There aren't any problems with `::` and delayed expansion

Comment: @jeb and why #Azevedo's comment has 17 upvotes then?

Comment: The amount of upvotes makes @Azevedo comment not correct. There is only a problem inside of parenthesis blocks with `::`, see also [Unexpected “The system cannot find the drive specified.”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19847135/463115)

Comment: I've tested `::` on my scripts. It may may bug some scripts as I mentioned. Ok. go ahead and use `::` because it "looks cool"

Comment: @Azevedo Let's talk here [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183550/room-for-jeb-and-azevedo)

Comment: ++ **Note that, a `%` in `REM` or `::` may cause an Error** -- they are not truly comments.
++ 
++ Try to run the following `.bat` -> it blinks, but does nothing: 
`REM This line is causing an Error %~nxf`
`echo This line will not be printed.`
`pause`
++ 
++ For more info: https://superuser.com/questions/1610492/why-does-this-batch-file-fail-on-a-rem-line
++ 
++ (not sure why no one points this out)

Comment: @Nor.Z perfect catch! If you wish, I'll add your note that in answer.

Answer (score 58):

No, plain old batch files use `REM` as a comment.  `ECHO` is the command that prints something on the screen.

To "comment out" sections of the file you could use `GOTO`.  An example of all these commands/techniques:

```
REM it starts here the section below can be safely erased once the file is customised
ECHO Hey you need to edit this file before running it!  Check the instructions inside
ECHO Now press ctrl-c to interrupt execution or enter to continue
PAUSE
REM erase the section above once you have customised the file
python executed1.py
ECHO Skipping some stuff now
GOTO End
python skipped1.py
python skipped2.py
:END
python executed2.py
```

What can I say?  batch files are a relic of times long gone, they're clunky and ugly.

You can read more [on this website](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php).

EDIT: modified the example a bit to have it contain the elements you are apparently looking for.

Answer (score 37):

The :: instead of REM was preferably used in the days that computers weren't very fast.
REM'ed line are read and then ingnored. ::'ed line are ignored all the way. This could speed up your code in "the old days". Further more after a REM you need a space, after :: you don't.

And as said in the first comment: you can add info to any line you feel the need to

```
SET DATETIME=%DTS:~0,8%-%DTS:~8,6% ::Makes YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS
```

As for the skipping of parts.
Putting REM in front of every line can be rather time consuming.
As mentioned using GOTO to skip parts is an easy way to skip large pieces of code. Be sure to set a :LABEL at the point you want the code to continue.

```
SOME CODE

GOTO LABEL  ::REM OUT THIS LINE TO EXECUTE THE CODE BETWEEN THIS GOTO AND :LABEL

SOME CODE TO SKIP
.
LAST LINE OF CODE TO SKIP

:LABEL
CODE TO EXECUTE
```

Comment: How can a double-colon line be ignored without being read? Mustn't the interpreter first read the line before recognizing it as a double-colon line?

Comment: @RobKennedy as I read the answer, it does not read anything after the ::, where everything after REM is read.

Comment: If the command interpreter *stops reading*, @James, then it would never execute any more of the file. It obviously needs to continue reading to discover where the comment ends and where next line of the file begins. It has to do that with `::` and `rem` equally.

Comment: @RobKennedy, I also thought it was implied that it only applied to the line the command was on.

Comment: Either way, the interpreter has to read the line.  If it's `rem` it also has to execute it, but if it's `::` it doesn't.

Comment: @RobKennedy it does **read** but it does not **parse** (or process) what it reads, it just skips until the next `\n` and then starts parsing again [citation needed]

Comment: And when it /does/ parse a label, (as it does sometimes inside IF blocks), you get errors like:  ') was unexpected at this time', or 'The system cannot find the drive specified.'

Comment: @JamesJenkins The voice of reason. (And reading comments properly!!)

Comment: TIL! Thanks for the history lesson!

Answer (score 32):

### Multi line comments

If there are large number of lines you want to comment out then it will be better if you can make multi line comments rather than commenting out every line.

See [this post by Rob van der Woude on comment blocks](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php):

> The batch language doesn't have comment blocks, though there are ways
>   to accomplish the effect.
>
> ```
> GOTO EndComment1
> This line is comment.
> And so is this line.
> And this one...
> :EndComment1
> ```
>
> You can use `GOTO` Label and :Label for making block comments.
>
> Or, If the comment block appears at the end of the batch file, you can
>   write `EXIT` at end of code and then any number of comments for your
>   understanding.
>
> ```
> @ECHO OFF
> REM Do something
>   •
>   •
> REM End of code; use GOTO:EOF instead of EXIT for Windows NT and later
> EXIT
>
> Start of comment block at end of batch file
> This line is comment.
> And so is this line.
> And this one...
> ```

Comment: this is often used in hybrid batch & VBS/JS scripts, although they used if `if` instead of `goto` http://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/995714 http://ss64.com/vb/syntax-hybrid.html http://stackoverflow.com/a/34512715/995714

Answer (score 15):

### Putting comments on the same line with commands: use `& :: comment`

```
color C          & :: set red font color
echo IMPORTANT INFORMATION
color            & :: reset the color to default
```

**Explanation:**

[`&` separates two commands](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490954.aspx), so in this case `color C` is the first command and `:: set red font color` is the second one.

---

#### Important:

This statement with comment looks intuitively correct:

```
goto error1         :: handling the error
```

but it is **not a valid use** of the comment. It works only because `goto` ignores all arguments past the first one. The proof is easy, this `goto` will not fail either:

```
goto error1 handling the error
```

But similar attempt

```
color 17            :: grey on blue
```

fails executing the command due to 4 arguments unknown to the `color` command: `::`, `grey`, `on`, `blue`.

It will only work as:

```
color 17     &      :: grey on blue
```

**So the ampersand is inevitable.**

Comment: From other answers, it seems that the ampersand is not needed?

Comment: @Snaptastic – The other answers are actually wrong in this point, see my recent edit.

Comment: This seems to be the correct way; It even gets highlighted as comment in my IDE.

Answer (score 10):

You can comment something out using `::` or `REM`:

```
your commands here
:: commenttttttttttt
```

or

```
your commands here
REM  commenttttttttttt
```

To do it on the same line as a command, you must add an ampersand:

```
your commands here      & ::  commenttttttttttt
```

or

```
your commands here      & REM  commenttttttttttt
```

## Note:

- Using **`::`**  in nested logic (`IF-ELSE`, `FOR` loops, etc...) will cause an error. In those cases, use **`REM`** instead.

Comment: This is based on T.Todua's answer. I felt that their answer was good but left out some important details, but they rolled back my edit, so I'm turning my revision into its own answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Commenting a line

For commenting line use [REM or ::](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/388389) though `::`  might [fail inside brackets](https://ss64.com/nt/rem.html)

within delayed expansion lines starting with `!<delimiter>` will be ignored so this can be used for comments:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

echo delayed expansion activated
!;delayed expansion commented line
echo end of the demonstration
```

### Comment at the end of line

For comments at the end of line you can again use `rem` and `::` combined with `&`:

```
echo --- &:: comment (should not be the last line in the script)
echo --- &rem comment
```

### Commenting at the end of file

As noting will be parsed after the `exit` command you can use it to put comments at the end of the file:

```
@echo off

echo commands

exit /b 

-------------------
commnts at the end 
of the file
------------------
```

### Inline comments

Expansion of not existing variables is replaced with nothing ,and as setting a variable with `=` rather hard you can [use this for inline comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411082/388389):

```
@echo off

echo long command %= this is a comment =% with an inline comment
```

### Multiline comments

For multiline comments `GOTO` (for outside brackets) and `REM` with conditional execution (for inside brackets) can be used. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28522310/388389):

```
@echo off

echo starting script

goto :end_comments
 comented line 
 one more commented line
:end_comments

echo continue with the script

(
    echo demonstration off
    rem/||(
      lines with
      comments
    )
    echo multiline comment inside
    echo brackets
)
```

And the same technique beautified with macros:

```
@echo off

::GOTO comment macro
set "[:=goto :]%%"
::brackets comment macros
set "[=rem/||(" & set "]=)"

::testing
echo not commented 1

%[:%
  multi 
  line
  comment outside of brackets
%:]%

echo not commented 2

%[:%
  second multi 
  line
  comment outside of brackets
%:]%

::GOTO macro cannot be used inside for
for %%a in (first second) do (
    echo first not commented line of the %%a execution
    %[%
        multi line
        comment
    %]%
    echo second not commented line of the %%a execution
)
```

Comment: Interesting... Wanted to comment out a wrong batch var expansion and using:
`REM echo ~dp*= %~dp*`
or
`%= echo ~dp*= %~dp* =%`
didn't work. Combining both it finally worked:
`rem %= echo ~dp*= %~dp* =%`

Comment: @hexaae - arguments expansion is with higher priority during parsing. Good that you've found a way to comment it.

Comment: @hexaae - it works because cmd takes `%= echo ~dp*= %` as a variable. The lonely `~` as a command and then it is commented with REM. Though a good way to avoid the `REM %~` bug

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use:

- REM for comments
- &REM for inline comments

Example:

```
@echo off
set parameter1=%1%
REM test if the parameter 1 was received
if defined parameter1 echo The parameter 1 is %parameter1% &REM Display the parameter
```

Comment: I can't see where your answer add any more information. There are already answers with the same content, at least one is 8 years old

Comment: It's a simplest answer...without complexity

Comment: @JorgeCribb not very clear

Answer (score 2):

You can add comments to the end of a batch file with this syntax:

```
@echo off
:: Start of code
...
:: End of code

(I am a comment
So I am!
This can be only at the end of batch files
```

Just make sure you never use a closing parentheses.

Attributions: Leo Guttirez Ramirez on https://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php

Answer (score 1):

This is an old topic and I'd like to add my understanding here to expand the knowledge of this interesting topic.

The key difference between REM and :: is:

REM is a command itself, while :: is NOT.

We can treat :: as a token that as soon as CMD parser encounters the first non-blank space in a line is this :: token, it will just skip the whole line and read next line. That's why REM should be followed by at least a blank space to be able to function as a comment for the line, while :: does not need any blank space behind it.

That REM is a command itself can be best understood from the following [FOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) syntax

The basic FOR syntax is as follows

```
FOR %v in (set) DO <Command> [command param]
```

here `<Command>` can be any valid command
So we can write the following valid command line as `rem` is a command

```
FOR %i in (1,2,3) DO rem echo %i
```

However, we CANNOT write the following line as `::` is not a command

```
FOR %i in (1,2,3) DO :: echo %i
```

Comment: technically, `::` is an (invalid) label (which explains it's behavior) and so should not be used (although it's still quite common)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `::` or `rem` for comments.

When commenting, use `::` as it's 3 times faster. An example is shown [here](https://www.thebateam.org/forum/how-to/rem-vs-colons-for-batch-script-comments/)

Only if comments are in `if`, use `rem`, as the colons could make errors, because they are a label.