# ELSE was unexpected at this time batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

This is the script:

```
@echo off

set BSL_Scripter_go="BSL_Scripter.exe"
set BSL_Script=WriteMain_s.txt
set yes=Y
set no=N


::%BSL_Scripter_go% %BSL_Script%

:LABEL1
set /p answer=Have you turned device off?[Y\N]

IF "%answer%"=="%yes%" (GOTO LABEL_DEVICE_RUN
) ELSE (IF "%answer%"=="%no%"(GOTO LABEL1) ELSE (GOTO LABEL_TYPO))

:LABEL_DEVICE_RUN
echo Device is runing..
GOTO END

:LABEL_TYPO
echo UNCORRECT ANSWER, PLEASE TYPE 'Y' or 'N'
GOTO LABEL1

:END
```

and I got the error:

```
ELSE was unexpected at this time
```

Little help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> missing between `"%no%"` and `(GOTO LABEL1)`:

```
IF "%answer%"=="%no%" (GOTO LABEL1)
```

Otherwise, `"%no%"(GOTO` is the string to compare and so there a closing `)` too much. The command line interpreter tries to execute the following line (omitting values and commands for visualisation):

```
IF <value>==<value> (command) ELSE (IF value==value command) ELSE (command))
```

You will notice that it looks like there are two `ELSE` clauses for the first `IF` statement.

*Side Note:* I recommend using `/IF /I "%answer%"==...` so that `Y`/`N` and `y`/`n` are accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This drove me nuts. In my case it was unescaped`()` in my comment lines prefixed with `::` inside my `IF` statements.

Apparently one should be using REM inside `IF` statements instead of `::`, but escaping all my `^(`m `^)` (even in non-comment lines, i.e. `ECHO` statements) worked for me.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839602/913223