# START /WAIT causing "More?" after execution (CMD)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this little script below that I upload to GitHub to automate some processes:

**script.bat** (uploaded to GitHub)

```
@echo off
set "folder=%random%%random%%random%"
mkdir "%temp%\%folder%"
cd "%temp%\%folder%"
curl --silent <link> >mainfile.bat
curl --silent <link> >mainfile2.bat
curl --silent <link> >mainfile3.bat
curl --silent <link> >mainfile4.bat
curl --silent <link> >mainfile5.bat
::some tasks involving downloaded batch files here...
del mainfile3.bat
del mainfile4.bat
del mainfile5.bat
start /wait mainfile.bat 2>nul
rmdir "%temp%\%folder%"
```

I run this file by running `curl --silent https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***/***/main/script.bat|cmd /q /k` on my computer.

The thing is, i saw `More?` at the end of the console and I don't know why. Tried to run the script again with `|cmd /k` and saw that it happens after `start /wait mainfile.bat 2>nul`.

This wasn't an issue before and I cannot find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Why are you using `start` in the first place? That's not a CMD command, it's a call to Windows Explorer to start an application using the Windows Shell. Also `.bat` is the extension used by DOS 30 years ago. The extension used by Windows is `.cmd`. Finally, if you want string interpolation you should look to PowerShell instead of trying to replicate the same effect in the old shell

Comment: Also don't use `::` for comments. Use `REM`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos 1. I use `start` because I need `script.bat` to pause until the called script (in my example that is `mainfile.bat`) terminates, then delete the whole folder. 2. `.bat` and `.cmd` works the same way and Windows 11 still recognizes `.bat` so I don't think it really matters. 3. I find PowerShell a bit complicated to use and I'm a beginner so I think I'll stick to CMD for now.

Comment: @rzickler I don't see any differences between the two.

Comment: If you want to wait for another batch to finish use `CALL mainfile.bat ...`. Just because you don't see the differences doesn't mean they aren't there. Using random snippets you got from google searches isn't a great idea either. It's not just `start`, but even mentioning `|cmd /k` suggests you're using google searches instead of the docs. There's rarely any good reason to start a new shell in a batch.

Comment: PowerShell is easier and *simpler* for beginners because it has great docs, online help, lots of books and courses and is even supported in VS Code. There are libraries of ready-made PowerShell scripts available too. CMD has none of that. If you insist on using CMD though, I suggest using [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html) as a reference

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I used `|cmd /k` instead of `|cmd /q /k` to find where the bug is. I **did not** use any Google search results when making the script, only ss64.com.

Comment: @ItsSuperPlayz have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16839602/16104038 and here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16632555/16104038 The double colon is basically still a label but more precise an invalid label that is ignored by the command processor. `REM` is intended for comments `::` is not

Comment: Your `rmdir "%temp%\%folder%"` line will not remove the directory, it will only empty it of files, because it is the current working directory. That means you'd end up with an unnecessary directory with a random name residing in `%Temp%`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a batch script according to what you posted, with the correct `Call` command, (rather than `Start`), and other improvements.

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

:TmpDir
Set "folder=%Temp%\%RANDOM%%RANDOM%%RANDOM%"

If Exist "%folder%\." (GoTo TmpDir) Else MD "%folder%" 2>NUL

PushD "%folder%" 2>NUL || Exit /B

%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe --silent "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***" 1>"mainfile.cmd"
%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe --silent "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***" 1>"mainfile2.cmd"
%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe --silent "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***" 1>"mainfile3.cmd"
%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe --silent "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***" 1>"mainfile4.cmd"
%SystemRoot%\System32\curl.exe --silent "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/***" 1>"mainfile5.cmd"

Rem some tasks involving downloaded batch files here...

Del /Q "mainfile3.cmd" "mainfile4.cmd" "mainfile5.cmd"
Call "mainfile.cmd" 2>NUL

PopD

RD "%folder%"
```

I should add, if you are running scripts `mainfile2.cmd`, `mainfile3.cmd`, `mainfile4.cmd`, or `mainfile5.cmd` before you `Del`ete them, prepend those with `Call` as with the `mainfile.cmd` shown.

It should be noted however, that none of your `Call`ed scripts should terminate with `Exit`, (If they do, remove it, or if necessary, replace it with `Exit /B` or `GoTo :EOF`).

I should also mention that, if the scripts `mainfile3.cmd`, `mainfile4.cmd`, or `mainfile5.cmd` aren't something which should be ignored by a glob/wildcard within `mainfile.cmd`, you can just remove the `Del` line, (as those will be handled by the `RD` command anyhow).

Comment: Can I somehow make `RD "%folder%"` work even if the user hits X on top-right corner?

Comment: You expect a process to continue when you explicitly hard-kill it?

Comment: There's something particularly dodgy about  downloading scripts from the internet, creating randomly named files with them to bypass any security messages, them trying to force a deletion to prevent the end user knowing what you did. Why would the end user hit the X?

Comment: I want `rd "%folder%"` to be executed even if user hits X (my script never ends by itself, the only ways to exit is by selecting the exit option or hitting X). That's why I used `start /wait` in the first place.