# Which comment style should I use in batch files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, coding-style, comments

I've been writing some batch files, and I ran into [this user guide](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=307), which has been quite informative. One thing it showed me was that lines can be commented not just with `REM`, but also with `::`. It says:

> Comments in batch code can be made by using a double-colon, this is better than using the REM command because labels are processed before redirection symbols. `::<remark>` causes no problems but `rem <remark>` produces errors.

Why then, do most guides and examples I see use the `REM` command? Does `::` work on all versions of Windows?

Comment: Just for the record, I've seen problems when "REM" is used to comment out a line with redirection under Windows 98.

Comment: As an aside, in line with @Digger's comment: The linked guide is for _DOS_ (`command.exe`), not `cmd.exe`, the _NT_ command processor as found on Windows 2000 onward. `rem <remark>` works just fine in the latter (since _at least_ Windows XP), and `REM` is the official constracnt and the safest choice overall; while `::` has its advantages, it is ultimately a hack that is problematic inside `(…)` blocks (as discussed in many answers here).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "comment-out" (add comment) in a batch/cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269338/how-to-comment-out-add-comment-in-a-batch-cmd)

Comment: So, what situation with REM causes errors exactly?

Answer (score 409, accepted):

**tl;dr:** `REM` is the documented and supported way to embed comments in batch files.

---

`::` is essentially a blank label that can never be jumped to, whereas `REM` is an actual command that just does nothing. In neither case (at least on Windows 7) does the presence of redirection operators cause a problem.

However, `::` is known to misbehave in blocks under certain circumstances, being parsed not as a label but as some sort of drive letter. I'm a little fuzzy on where exactly but that alone is enough to make me use `REM` exclusively. It's the documented and supported way to embed comments in batch files whereas `::` is merely an artifact of a particular implementation.

---

Here is an example where `::` produces a problem in a `FOR` loop.

This example will *not* work in a file called `test.bat` on your desktop:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test.bat') do (
    ::echo hello>C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\text.txt
)
pause
```

While this example will work as a comment correctly:

```
@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('type C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\test.bat') do (
    REM echo hello>C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\text.txt
)
pause
```

The problem appears to be when trying to redirect output into a file. My best guess is that it is interpreting `::` as an escaped label called `:echo`.

Comment: @Firedan: Is the name of the batch file and its location relevant (along with the name and location of the file to redirect to?). Otherwise it'd be nice to simplify the example.

Comment: If there's delayed variable usage in line, :: will cause some error messages, e.g. Can not find specificed disk driver..... So better use REM then.

Comment: :: comments are parsed, and special characters like > | end the comment, and the following text is not commented.

Comment: @mosh is right. For instance, `%VAR%` variables are expanded. Suppose you have (wrongly) `set TARGET=C:\Program Files (x86)\"foo.exe"`, and inside a `DO(..)` expression you have `:: echo %TARGET%` you will get an error because the `(x86)` gets expanded _before_ the whole expression gets evaluated, leading to an invalid `DO(..)` expression and _very_ inexplicable errors (in this case _"\Microsoft was unexpected at this time"_). You don't even need `|` or `>` in your expression. A `::` is not a real comment, `REM` is, though.

Comment: Came here getting all kinds of errors from my batch script. Changed all of my `::` comments to `REM`, everything started working. Was not aware `::` was a hack!

Answer (score 187):

### Comments with REM

A `REM` can remark a complete line, also a multiline caret at the line end, if it's not the end of the first token.

```
REM This is a comment, the caret is ignored^
echo This line is printed

REM This_is_a_comment_the_caret_appends_the_next_line^
echo This line is part of the remark
```

REM followed by some characters `.:\/=` works a bit different, it doesn't comment an ampersand, so you can use it as inline comment.

```
echo First & REM. This is a comment & echo second
```

But to avoid problems with existing files like `REM`, `REM.bat` or `REM;.bat` only a modified variant should be used.

```
REM^;<space>Comment
```

And for the character `;` is also allowed one of `;,:\/=`

REM is about **6 times slower** than `::` (tested on Win7SP1 with 100000 comment lines).
For a normal usage it's not important (58µs versus 360µs per comment line)

### Comments with ::

A `::` always *executes* a line end caret.

```
:: This is also a comment^
echo This line is also a comment
```

Labels and also the *comment label* `::` have a special logic in parenthesis blocks.
They span always two lines [SO: goto command not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006006/463115).
So they are not recommended for parenthesis blocks, as they are often the cause for syntax errors.

With `ECHO ON` a `REM` line is shown, but not a line commented with `::`

Both can't really comment out the rest of the line, so a simple `%~`  will cause a syntax error.

```
REM This comment will result in an error %~ ...
```

But REM is able to stop the batch parser at an early phase, even before the special character phase is done.

```
@echo ON
REM This caret ^ is visible
```

[You can use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29853831/52277) &REM or &:: to add a comment to the end of command line.
This approach works because '&' introduces a new command on the same line.

### Comments with percent signs  %= comment =%

There exists a comment style with percent signs.

In reality these are variables but they are expanded to nothing.
But the advantage is that they can be placed in the same line, even without `&`.
The equal sign ensures, that such a variable can't exists.

```
echo Mytest
set "var=3"     %= This is a comment in the same line=%
```

The percent style is recommended for batch macros, as it doesn't change the runtime behaviour, as the comment will be removed when the macro is defined.

```
set $test=(%\n%
%=Start of code=% ^
echo myMacro%\n%
)
```

### Performance `REM` vs `::` vs `%= =%`

In short:

- `::` and `%= =%` seems to have the same performance
- `REM` takes ~ 50% more time than `::`
- In blocks, especially loops only `REM` consumes time, but `::` is removed from the cached block when the block is parsed, therefore  **it consumes no time**

For more info see [SO: Question about Comments in Batch *.bat files and speed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68436626/463115)

Comment: It should be noted that `%=` comments are finicky with quotation marks, i.e. `set foo=bar %=baz` results in `foo` expanding to `bar %=baz`, as does `set foo="bar" %=baz`, whereas only `set "foo=bar" %=baz` results in `foo` expanding to `bar` as intended.

Comment: @LastStar007: Always using quoting style `set "foo=bar"` is worth recommending in general, because it is the most robust form that clearly delimits the value.
The issue you're describing is inherent in _`set`'s_ behavior, and not specific to `%= … =%` comments: unless you use `"var=val"` quoting, `set` considers everything that follows the `=` the value, including trailing whitespace (through the end of the line or, if applicable, the start of the next inline command).

Comment: _In blocks, especially loops only `REM` consumes time, but `::` is removed from the cached block when the block is parsed, therefore **it consumes no time**_ – probably not, otherwise it wouldn't cause errors [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843849/11725753).

Answer (score 37):

### Analysis of commenting techniques in Windows batch files

This answer attempts a **pragmatic summary** of the many great answers on this page.

<sup>[jeb's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/45375) deserves special mention, because it goes in-depth and covers many edge cases.

Notably, he points out that a misconstructed variable/parameter reference such as `%~` can break *any* of the solutions below - including `REM` lines.</sup>

---

#### *Whole-line* comments - the only directly supported style:

- **`REM`** (or case variations thereof) is the **only official comment construct**, and is the **safest choice** - see [Joey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407934/45375).
- **`::` is a (widely used) *hack***, which has **pros and cons**:

  - **Pros**:

    - *Visual distinctiveness* and, possibly, ease of typing.
    - *Speed*, although that will probably rarely matter - see [jeb's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/45375) and [Rob van der Woude's excellent blog post](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php).
  - **Cons**:

    - **Inside `(...)` blocks, `::` can *break* the command**, and the **rules for safe use are restrictive and not easy to remember** - see below.

---

**If you *do* want to use `::`**, you have these choices:

- *Either*: To be safe, make an exception inside `(...)` blocks and use `REM` there, or do not place comments *inside* `(...)` altogether.
- *Or*: Memorize the **painfully restrictive rules for safe use of `::` inside `(...)`**, which are summarized in the following snippet:

```
@echo off

for %%i in ("dummy loop") do (

  :: This works: ONE comment line only, followed by a DIFFERENT, NONBLANK line.
  date /t

  REM If you followed a :: line directly with another one, the *2nd* one
  REM would generate a spurious "The system cannot find the drive specified."
  REM error message and potentially execute commands inside the comment.
  REM In the following - commented-out - example, file "out.txt" would be
  REM created (as an empty file), and the ECHO command would execute.
  REM   :: 1st line
  REM   :: 2nd line > out.txt & echo HERE

  REM NOTE: If :: were used in the 2 cases explained below, the FOR statement
  REM would *break altogether*, reporting:
  REM  1st case: "The syntax of the command is incorrect."
  REM  2nd case: ") was unexpected at this time."

  REM Because the next line is *blank*, :: would NOT work here.

  REM Because this is the *last line* in the block, :: would NOT work here.
)
```

---

#### Emulation of *other comment styles* - inline and multi-line:

Note that *none of these styles are directly supported by the batch language*, but can be *emulated*.

---

**Inline comments**:

<sup>* The code snippets below use `ver` as a stand-in for an arbitrary command, so as to facilitate experimentation.  
* To make `SET` commands work correctly with inline comments, double-quote the `name=value` part; e.g., `SET "foo=bar"`.<sup>[1]</sup></sup>

In this context we can distinguish two subtypes:

- **EOL comments** ([to-the-]end-of-line), which  can be placed after a command, and invariably extend to the end of the line (again, courtesy of [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/45375)):

  - `ver & REM <comment>` takes advantage of the fact that `REM` is a valid command and `&` can be used to place an additional command after an existing one.
  - `ver & :: <comment>` works too, but is *really only usable outside of `(...)` blocks*, because its safe use there is even more limited than using `::` standalone.
- **Intra-line comments**, which be placed *between* multiple commands on a line or ideally even *inside* of a given command.
  Intra-line comments are the most flexible (single-line) form and **can by definition also be used as EOL comments.**

  - `ver & REM^. ^<comment^> & ver` allows **inserting a comment *between commands*** (again, courtesy of [jeb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12408045/45375)), but note how `<` and `>` needed to be `^`-escaped, because **the following chars. cannot be used as-is: `< > |`** (whereas unescaped `&` or `&&` or `||` start the *next* command).
  - `%= <comment> =%`, as detailed in [dbenham's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411082/45375), is the **most flexible form**, because it **can be placed *inside* a command (among the arguments)**.
    It takes advantage of variable-expansion syntax in a way that ensures that the expression always expands to the *empty string* - **as long as the comment text contains neither `%` nor `:`**
    Like `REM`, `%= <comment> =%` works well both outside and inside `(...)` blocks, but it is more visually distinctive; the only down-sides are that it is harder to type, easier to get wrong syntactically, and not widely known, which can hinder understanding of source code that uses the technique.

---

**Multi-line (whole-line block) comments**:

- [James K's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456726/45375) shows how to use a **`goto` statement and a label** to delimit a multi-line comment of arbitrary length and content (which in his case he uses to store usage information).
- [Zee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22157775/45375) shows how to use a **"null label"** to create a multi-line comment, although care must be taken to terminate all interior lines with `^`.
- [Rob van der Woude's blog post](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php) mentions another somewhat obscure option that allows you to ***end* a file with an arbitrary number of comment lines**: An ***opening `(` only* causes everything that comes after to be ignored**, as long as it doesn't contain a ( non-`^`-escaped) `)`, i.e., as long as the block is not *closed*.

---

<sup>[1] Using `SET "foo=bar"` to define variables - i.e., putting double quotes around the name and `=` and the value *combined* - is necessary in commands such as `SET "foo=bar" & REM Set foo to bar.`, so as to ensure that what *follows* the intended variable value (up to the next command, in this case a single space) doesn't accidentally become part of it.

(As an aside: `SET foo="bar"` would not only not avoid the problem, it would make the double quotes *part of the value*).

Note that this problem is inherent to `SET` and even applies to *accidental* trailing whitespace following the value, so **it is advisable to *always* use the `SET "foo=bar"` approach.**</sup>

Answer (score 31):

Another alternative is to express the comment as a variable expansion that always expands to nothing.

Variable names cannot contain `=`, except for undocumented dynamic variables like
`%=ExitCode%` and `%=C:%`. No variable name can ever contain an `=` after the 1st position. So I sometimes use the following to include comments within a parenthesized block:

```
::This comment hack is not always safe within parentheses.
(
  %= This comment hack is always safe, even within parentheses =%
)
```

It is also a good method for incorporating in-line comments

```
dir junk >nul 2>&1 && %= If found =% echo found || %= else =% echo not found
```

The leading `=` is not necessary, but I like if for the symmetry.

There are two restrictions:

1) the comment cannot contain `%`

2) the comment cannot contain `:`

Comment: LOL! Make it one oversized variable! Genius! `%=ExitCode%`? Neat. Learn something new every day!

Comment: You imply that the trailing `=` is necessary. But it does not seem to be.

Comment: @JamesK - I use the trailing `=` so that something like %=ExitCode=% is a "comment" and not a dynamic variable. I prefer to use a style that always works (except for limitations noted at bottom of answer of course).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20169219/1689714 for an exploration of the dynamic variables (e.g. %=ExitCode% %=ExitCodeAscii% %=C:% %=D:% %__CD__% etc.), what they mean, how they are set, etc..

Answer (score 27):

After I realized that I could use label `::` to make comments and comment out code `REM` just looked plain ugly to me. As has been mentioned the double-colon can cause problems when used inside `()` blocked code, but I've discovered a work-around by alternating between the labels `::` and `:`<kbd>space</kbd>

```
:: This, of course, does
:: not cause errors.

(
  :: But
   : neither
  :: does
   : this.
)
```

It's not ugly like `REM`, and actually adds a little style to your code.

So outside of code blocks I use `::` and inside them I alternate between `::` and `:`.

By the way, for large hunks of comments, like in the header of your batch file, you can avoid special commands and characters completely by simply `goto`ing over your comments.  This let's you use any method or style of markup you want, despite that fact that if `CMD` ever actually tried to processes those lines it'd throw a hissy.

```
@echo off
goto :TopOfCode

=======================================================================
COOLCODE.BAT

Useage:
  COOLCODE [/?] | [ [/a][/c:[##][a][b][c]] INPUTFILE OUTPUTFILE ]

Switches:
       /?    - This menu
       /a    - Some option
       /c:## - Where ## is which line number to begin the processing at.
         :a  - Some optional method of processing
         :b  - A third option for processing
         :c  - A forth option
  INPUTFILE  - The file to process.
  OUTPUTFILE - Store results here.

 Notes:
   Bla bla bla.

:TopOfCode
CODE
.
.
.
```

Use what ever notation you wish `*`'s, `@`'s etc.

Comment: How do you handle the `/?` switch to make it print this menu ?

Comment: @hoang
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION <NEWLINE>
set var=%~1 <NEWLINE>

echo first param is %1 <NEWLINE>

IF !VAR!=="/?" ( GOTO USAGE ) <NEWLINE>

:USAGE <NEWLINE>

echo blah blah.. <NEWLINE>

Comment: Alternating single and double colons must be a headache when you insert or delete a row.

Comment: @GL2014 basically you're saying "you **don't** print _this_ menu".  Your example code requires prefixing echo to each line of the usage notes.  James K's answer is misleading to the extent that it suggests there is some way to print the usage notes as written .

Comment: @Timbo I wrote a subroutine (`:PrintHelp`) for [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1330452/607984) that indeed does what @hoang asks for. I use <HELP> and </HELP> as markers but you can use whatever suits you.

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php) page tell that using "::" will be faster under certain constraints
Just a thing to consider when choosing

Comment: This is true, at least for Win7SP1, `::` can be 6 times faster than `REM`

Answer (score 4):

good question... I've been looking for this functionality for long too...

after several tests and tricks it seem the better solution is the more obvious one...

--> best way I found to do it, preventing parser integrity fail, is reusing REM:

```
echo this will show until the next REM &REM this will not show
```

you can also use multiline with the "NULL LABEL" trick... 
(dont forget the ^ at the end of the line for continuity)

```
::(^
this is a multiline^
comment... inside a null label!^
dont forget the ^caret at the end-of-line^
to assure continuity of text^ 
)
```

Answer (score 3):

James K, I'm sorry I was wrong in a fair portion of what I said.  The test I did was the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
  :: But
   : neither
  :: does
   : this
  :: also.
)
```

This meets your description of alternating but fails with a ") was unexpected at this time." error message.

I did some farther testing today and found that alternating isn't the key but it appears the key is having an even number of lines, not having any two lines in a row starting with double colons (::) and not ending in double colons. Consider the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
   : But
   : neither
   : does
   : this
   : cause
   : problems.
)
```

This works!

But also consider this:

```
@ECHO OFF
(
   : Test1
   : Test2
   : Test3
   : Test4
   : Test5
   ECHO.
)
```

The rule of having an even number of comments doesn't seems to apply when ending in a command.

Unfortunately this is just squirrelly enough that I'm not sure I want to use it.

Really, the best solution, and the safest that I can think of, is if a program like Notepad++ would read REM as double colons and then would write double colons back as REM statements when the file is saved.  But I'm not aware of such a program and I'm not aware of any plugins for Notepad++ that does that either.

Answer (score 2):

A very detailed and analytic discussion on the topic is available on [THIS](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php) page

It has the example codes and the pros/cons of different options.

Comment: You should summarize the contents of links provided in answers.  Otherwise it's called a "link only answer", and is completely useless if the link disappears.   In this case, the page pointed to is rather humorous in that it makes its choice based on optimising reading speed of batch files from slow floppy disk :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to comment in a batch file

**1)Using rem**

This is the official way. It apparently takes longer to execute than `::`, although it apparently stops parsing early, before the carets are processed. Percent expansion happens before rem and `::` are identified, so incorrect percent usage i.e. `%~` will cause errors if percents are present. Safe to use anywhere in code blocks.

**2)Using labels `:`, `::` or `:;` etc.**

For `:: comment`, ': comment' is an invalid label name because it *begins* with an invalid character. It is okay to use a colon in the middle of a label though. If a space begins at the start of label, it is removed `: label` becomes `:label`. If a space or a colon appears in the middle of the label, the rest of the name is not interpreted meaning that if there are two labels `:f:oo` and `:f rr`, both will be interpreted as `:f` and only the later defined label in the file will be jumped to. The rest of the label is effectively a comment. There are multiple alternatives to `::`, listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16639875/7194773). You can never `goto` or `call` a `::foo` label. `goto :foo` and `goto ::foo` will not work.

They work fine outside of code blocks but after a label in a code block, invalid or not, there has to be a valid command line. `:: comment` is indeed another valid command. It interprets it as a command and not a label; the command has precedence. Which is the command to cd to the `::` volume, which will work if you have executed `subst :: C:\`, otherwise you get a cannot find the volume error. That's why `:;` is arguably better because it cannot be interpreted in this way, and therefore is interpreted as a label instead, which serves as the valid command. This is not recursive, i.e, the next label does not need a command after it. That's why they come in twos.

You need to provide a valid command after the label e.g. `echo something`. A label in a code block has to come with at least one valid command, so the lines come in pairs of two. You will get an unexpected `)` error if there is a space or a closing parenthesis on the next line. If there is a space between the two `::` lines you will get an invalid syntax error.

You can also use the caret operator in the `::` comment like so:

```
@echo off

echo hello
(
   :;(^
   this^
   is^
   a^
   comment^
   )
   :;
)
   :;^
   this^
   is^
   a^
   comment
   :;
)
```

But you need the trailing `:;` for the reason stated above.

```
@echo off

(
echo hello
:;
:; comment
:; comment
:;
)
echo hello
```

It is fine as long as there is an even number. This is undoubtedly the best way to comment -- with 4 lines and `:;`. With `:;` you don't get any errors that need to be suppressed using `2> nul` or `subst :: C:\`. You could use `subst :: C:\` to make the volume not found error go away but it means you will have to also put C: in the code to prevent your working directory from becoming `::\`.

To comment at the end of a line you can do
`command &::` or `command & rem comment`, but there still has to be an even number, like so:

```
@echo off

(
echo hello & :;yes
echo hello & :;yes
:;
)

echo hello
```

The first `echo hello & :;yes` has a valid command on the next line but the second `& :;yes` does not, so it needs one i.e. the `:;`.

**3)Using an invalid environment variable**

`%= comment =%`. In a batch file, environment variables that are not defined are removed from the script. This makes it possible to use them at the end of a line without using `&`. It is custom to use an invalid environment variable i.e. one that contains an equals sign. The extra equals is not required but makes it look symmetrical. Also, variable names starting with "=" are reserved for undocumented dynamic variables. Those dynamic variables never end with "=", so by using an "=" at both the start and end of the comment, there is no possibility of a name clash. The comment cannot contain `%` or `:`.

```
@echo off 
echo This is an example of an %= Inline Comment =% in the middle of a line.
```

**4)As a command, redirecting stderr to nul**

```
@echo off
(
echo hello
;this is a comment 2> nul
;this is another comment  2> nul
)
```

**5)At the end of a file, everything after an unclosed parenthesis is a comment**

```
@echo off
(
echo hello
)

(this is a comment
this is a comment
this is a comment
```