# Batch test if variable is equal to a space

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my code, I am looping through each character in a string. I need to test if the character is a space.

This is my code:

```
if %str% == " " (
    ::echo Empty
    echo | set /p=%space%
    goto loopEnd
)
```

I have also tried:

```
if [%str%] == [" "] (
    ::echo Empty
    echo | set /p=%space%
    goto loopEnd
)
```

Both give the error

```
( was unexpected at this time.
```

Or

```
] was unexpected at this time.
```

I don't get errors testing for letters or numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: Don't use the double colon `::` (always use `rem`) to place comments inside blocks. The `::` syntax is treated as an empty  label and can produce weird behaviours and many syntax errors. [see jeb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407800/which-comment-style-should-i-use-in-batch-files/12408045#12408045) and also [Comments](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/comments.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting quotes around your variable.

```
if "%str%" == " " (
    ...
)
```

Comment: This works, thanks! How would I go about setting a variable to a space character? when I do 

    set space=  

I get nothing, and when I do set space=" " I get " "