# How to exit batch execution when php cli output is "NOTHING TO DO"

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-line-interface

I have a case that i need to exit the batch (.bat) program while executing a php script inside.

for example, this is my php code **echo.php**

```
<?php echo "NOTHING TO DO" ?>
```

and then i create a batch file to run it, this is just an example of my logic, but this is not work

```
@title "ECHO TEST"
@echo off
D:
cd D:\xampp\htdocs
SET status = "D:\xampp\htdocs\echo.php"
echo Status is %status%
pause
```

expected output is

```
Status is NOTHING TO DO
```

the final is i just need to know how to put php cli output into a variable of batch file so i can do condition for it.

Comment: Type `for /f` to parse command output.

Comment: @CatCat can u give me example?

Comment: Read help. Its in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for the response, so i got this solution loop untill the condition is meet with ur requirements

```
:loop

:: Parse token is like word, and delims mean like explode lol
:: Make parameter A for the output, and then define OUTPUT as the callback
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%A IN ('PHP PATH TO YOUR ACTION') DO SET OUTPUT=%%A

:: If condition
IF "%OUTPUT%" == "YOUR OUTPUT" (
    exit
) else (
    goto :loop
)
:: PS, my english is not really good
```

Comment: `REM` is the comment command **not** `::` which is a malformed `goto` lable.

Comment: thank you for information, but anyway my code is work with comment command like that :D

Comment: Writing deliberately wrong code *is wrong* and IT WILL NOT WORK where a lable is illegal. Consider this batch file `For %%A in (*) do (` , `echo %%A` , `::test`, then `)`. It will **CRASH**.

Comment: maybe this can be reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407800/which-comment-style-should-i-use-in-batch-files

Comment: One writes to spec, not to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `for /f` loop to parse the output of your `php` file. You have to modify your code, so it will do like this:

```bat
@title "ECHO TEST"
@echo off
cd /d D:\xampp\htdocs
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('D:\xampp\htdocs\echo.php') do set "status=%%A"
echo Status is %status%
pause
```

Hope this helps!