# Redirect stdin to sub program in windows batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a kind of redirect script to stabilize the clang-format executable used by Visual studio over the different projects that I have.

For example:

- Project 1: Has .clang-format based on LLVM 5.0.0
- Project 2: Has .clang-format based on LLVM 8.0.0

So instead of using the default clang-format I'm trying to use a clang-format.cmd that based on the project has been using.

My current approach:

```
@echo OFF
:checkFormat
IF EXIST "clang-format.exe" ( 
   call clang-format.exe %* <&0 >&1
) ELSE (
   REM Loop the dir tree until the root the of the disk
   if "%cd:~3,1%"=="" (
      exit -1
   )
   cd ..
   goto checkFormat
)
```

However, whenever this script gets called from Visual Studio, I get an error:

> An error occurred while formatting with ClangFormat
> The pipe has been ended.

I've tried replacing the call with another cmd that prints something to file and it doesn't seem to be to called.
However, I did already add similar file creation before the 'call', which confirms it is being reached and in the directory that I expect.

How do I verify what the content is of STDIN? How do I redirect this stdin to the actual executable?

*EDIT* When running from within a CMD-prompt, it gives following error:

> The handle could not be duplicated
> during redirection of handle 0.

Comment: The proper command to provide comment within a batch file is `Rem` not `::`, whilst `::` can work, it is problematic within a parenthesised block, please change it to `Rem Loop the dir tree until the root the of the disk`.

Comment: @Compo can you link to a more elaborate explanation on why this is?

Comment: @JVApen `::` is a broken label. It is not a standard `rem`ark method, inside the code block it will cause some issues most of the time.

Comment: Yes @JVApen, you can start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12407934).

Comment: Adapted, tested, no change

Comment: what is the reason for `call`ing the executable? you also say you are calling it from visual studio, does the same error occur when you run the script manually? Lastly, why this aproach? why not search for the exe and run it instead?

Comment: Why are you climbing down the tree, one step at a time? Do you not know the locations of the different versions of `clang-format.exe`?

Comment: Visual studio launches it in the directory of the file. I know it's in the root of the project, however, I don't know where this root is. As all is in subversion, I don't even have an absolute path.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I've actually forgot to run it from the CMD directly. Gives `The handle could not be duplicated during redirection of handle 0.` The `call` is just trying things out, might indeed not be OK. I've have to give VS an 'executable' in the configuration which gets called on format by VS

Comment: Remove ` <&0 >&1` they are useless and wrong

Comment: Removing the `call` and the `<&0 >&1` seem to have solved the problem. Thanks for all the effort!

Comment: @jeb.. how about posting an answer? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the part `<&0 >&1`, because the constructs are wrong.

`>&1` will be interpreted as

> append handle 1 (STDOUT) to handle 1 (STDOUT)

That can't work.

The `<0&` will be interpreted nearly the same way

> append handle 0 (STDIN) to handle 0 (STDIN)