# How to fix "The syntax of the command is incorrect." error

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a CYOA game through .bat files. I want the user to be in a loop until they want to leave but I can't get an IF inside the loop (the conditional to exit) to work.

```
set "can1=0"

:w1
    :: vvv I think it's this line that doesn't work vvv
    if not "%can1%"=="1" (
        if /i "%r1%"=="look around" (
            echo Anything else?
            set /p r1=":: "
            goto :w1
        )
        :: ...
    ) else (
        echo Can continue...
    )

    endlocal
```

I want the loop to continue until the player says something specific (I'll determine that later), but it gives the

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

error that seems to be case-specific.

Comment: Don't use `::` for comments, it's actually a label definition that *pretends* to be a comment, and it stuffs up complex loops and conditionals. Use `rem` instead.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks! That worked. (like it actually got rid of the error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which comment style should I use in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407800/which-comment-style-should-i-use-in-batch-files)