# Batch file to stop services 18 in total then delete files and then restart services

Tags: batch-file

I have around 140 virtual servers that need regular maintance, they all run message queuing, but the storage file needs to be kept below 512MB. I need to stop all the services in order and the last being MSMQ service, then go to the system32\msmg\storage file and delete all the *.mq files, once done I then would like the batch file to restart the services with the first being msmq. I also need to add some error messages, so if the service can not stop or start or its already running etc, below is what I think it should be like but not sure,.  may be there is a better way of doing it,
the plan would be to but the batch file on all the servers and set a sceduled task to Run the batch file.
Would it be possible to have an email generated to say that it has been completed successfully ?

```
NET STOP AVLDataService 2>&1|FIND "2182" 
IF errorlevel 1 goto :sub_already_stoped
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  A batch file can certainly accomplish this with `NET START/STOP` calls in the desired order. For error handling, if the error is non-fatal `echo` a message to a text file and continue.  If it's fatal, then use `goto` to jump to the end of the file. At the end of the file, you can email yourself the text file with error messages using [BMAIL](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm).

Comment: thanks for the reply, would it be better to have two batch files one for the net stop and the deletion of the *.mq files then a second batch file to net start ? at the bottom of the first batch file I would need to add some sort of pause to give it time to delete the *.mq files before starting the msmq service.

Comment: Since one's dependent on the other, keep them as one.  You can pause using `ping` or `timeout` [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos).

Comment: I dont quite know what is going wrong with my batch file, C:\Temp>NET STOP Message Queuing 2>&1 | FIND "2182" IF errorlevel 1 goto :sub_ already_stopped File not found - IF File not found - ERRORLEVEL File not found - 1 File not found - GOTO File not found - :SUB_ALREADY_STOPPED C:\Temp>ping 1.1.1.1 -n 20 1000 1>NUL I'm trying to stop the message queuing, but then I want to delete files in the msmq\storage folder the *.mq files like this del c:\windows\system32\msmq\Storage\*.mq /s it comes back with files in use which indiactes that the msmq is still running, any help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
title Service Uninstaller
color 0A

set blank=
set service=blank

:start
echo.
echo.
echo.
SET /P service=Enter the name of the service you want to uninstall:  

IF "%service%"=="" (ECHO Nothing is entered
GoTo :start)

cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo We will delete the service: %service%

ping -n 5 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul

::net stop %service%
ping -n 2 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul

sc delete %service%
pause

:end
```

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful to the OP