# How to lock the computer after executing an exe file using batch file programming in windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file program something like.

```
@echo off
start Mat.exe
>>Need a code here to runand check for termination of "Mat.exe"
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation

>>end of program
```

If anyone can help me set up the program so that I can lock my computer as soon as the "Mat.exe" file is terminated. I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Simply drop the `start` before `Mat.exe` so your batch-file will wait until `Mat.exe` has finished.

Edit: This only works if your `Mat.exe` runs in a console or similar.
If dropping the `start` didn't work you may have to check wheather or not `Mat.exe` is still running. For that I found a quite useful post, which should work for you: [How to wait for a process to terminate to execute another process in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch/8185270#8185270)

Edit2: Complete Code:

```
@echo off
:LOOP
start Mat.exe
TASKLIST 2>&1 | find "Mat.exe" > nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
) ELSE (
  SLEEP 3
  GOTO LOOP
)
```

You can adjust the `SLEEP` as you like, but i would suggest use at least 1 sec, otherwise you'll have 100% usage.

Comment: Not helpful at all, I need to run an OpenGL exe file that I made. I need to lock my computer as soon as it is terminated. How do I even get the exe file to start if I don't use the "start" command?

Comment: Just entering a valid filename is enough to start a programm, the start command opens a new window to run the program in it, so a batch-file won't block it's execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Start command with the /Wait switch. Here is an example:

```html
@echo off 
REM //start Mat.exe
start /wait [path of Mat.exe]
rundll32.exe user32.dll, LockWorkStation
```

Remember to use the 8.3 filenames and do not include  (" ") in the path string