# How to start a python program in a .BAT file without ending the .BAT script

Tags: batch-file

I need to run a python program and then move a file into a directory created by said program, only problem is once I run the python program it immediately ends the .BAT script.
this is the BAT file:

```
@ECHO off  
scrapy startproject work   
move script.py work\work\spiders  
cd work  
scrapy crawl script  
pause
```

Comment: It would significantly help if you supplied the BAT and PY files

Answer (score 1):

`scrapy` would seem to be a batch file so use `call` before it.

```
call scrapy param1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@echo off
start /W notepad
echo 1. Back from notepad  
start /W wordpad
echo 2. Back from wordpad
start /W notepad
echo 3. Back from notepad. Script done
```

Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch).