# efficient way to keep checking if a program is still running with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, process, interrupt

I would like to write a batch script, and part of the script I want to check if program1.exe is still running. Once program1.exe is no longer running, I want to do something.

I can write a while loop to do this, but it will keep checking over and over and use up 100% of one of my cores in my CPU.

Is there an efficient way to check? Maybe a hack that checks this condition once a second?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for a process to terminate to execute another process in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch)

Comment: @user3469517 the sleep command is not in all versions of windows and has been depreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a process is running via a batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162291/how-to-check-if-a-process-is-running-via-a-batch-script)

Comment: Did your batch script launch program1.exe?

Comment: Yes, my batch script launched program1.exe

Answer (score 2):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
Set "MyProcess=Notepad.exe"

:start
tasklist | find /i "%MyProcess%">nul && goto:wait || start %MyProcess%
goto:start

:wait
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
goto:start
```

Just replace Notepad.exe with the name of your program

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `for /f` loop with a `tasklist` to check for the process with a 1 sec timeout using the `ping` command (you can also use `timeout /t 1 >nul` instead).  The following example is from one of my scripts:

```
:CMBK
ping -a -n 1 127.0.0.1 1>2>nul
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=: " %%A IN ('tasklist /fi "imagename eq program1.exe" /fo list') do set imgnm=%%A
if not '%imgnm%'=='INFO' goto cmbk
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an efficient way to check? Maybe a hack that checks this condition once a second?

Use the `timeout /t 1` command.  If you don't want the "Waiting for 1 seconds, press a key to continue ..." message to appear, use `timeout /t 1 > nul`.