# How to execute several command in one file with a batch file?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I am actually writing a little PHP script, in order to retrieve files in folder on a FTP server and download them locally.
Another script put those file in the server.

So here's my question : how can I write a batch file that will execute the first php script, then run a program (a game in this case). 
When the game is closed, execute the second script.

So it will be this process :

1. When run the batch file, execute the first script (get file)
2. When all files are downloaded, run the programm (`game.exe`)
3. After game closing, execute the second script (put file)

I think at a `.bat` file, but maybe there is an another solution.

Thanks is advance !
Telest.

**EDIT :** 
Thanks for your answer.

Google gives me this post : [How to wait for a process to terminate to execute another process in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch-file).
I found that I can use `/W` in order to wait the program ends.

But `/W` seems not working. Tried `/WAIT` but no success.

Here is my batch file :

```
PHP C:\Users\PHProjects\test1.php
START /WAIT /B chrome.exe
PHP C:\Users\PHProjects\test2.php
PAUSE
```

(test1.php & test2.php are just dummy echo).

And the console result :

[Chrome executes well, but test2 too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLiQ2.png)

As you can see, Chrome executes well, but so do test2.php.

Is something wrong here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Using `.bat` file you could add something like `c:\path\to\php.exe -f "c:/path/to/script.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
call getfile.bat
start "" /w game.exe
call putfile.bat
```

see `start /?` and call /?. With `start` take note of the second half which details how not using start works (confusing I know}. `Call` details, as `start` details for programs, how it works calling a batch directly versus `call`.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my first post with new elements.