# Wait for a .bat file to close within a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to create a windows batch file (*.bat) file that only runs its commands if certain processes (and batch files) are NOT running.

I have looked at a solution that works for processes (*.exe) here:
[How to wait for a process to terminate to execute another process in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8177695/how-to-wait-for-a-process-to-terminate-to-execute-another-process-in-batch-file)

I want to do something very similar, however, there is one difficulty: Batch files show up as "cmd.exe" in the "TASKLIST" command.

I want to check if a specific bat file is running, for example: "C:\mybatch.bat", and if it is, wait until it is closed.

Comment: `tasklist /v` gives the window title. It's as if it's the window title - cmd doesn't bother changing the actual title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if a specific bat file `mybatch.bat` is running *could be* a tougher task than it could look at first sight.

Looking for a particular window title in `tasklist /V` as well as testing `CommandLine` property in `wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get CommandLine` *might fail* under some imaginable circumstance.

**1st**. Can you

- add `title ThisIsDistinguishingString` command at beginning of the `mybatch.bat` *and*
- remove all other `title` commands from `mybatch.bat` *and*
- ensure that  `mybatch.bat` **does not** call another batch script(s) containing a `title` command?

Then check `errorlevel` returned from [`find` command](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) as follows:

```
:testMybatch
tasklist /V /FI "imagename eq cmd.exe" | find "ThisIsDistinguishingString" > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    rem echo mybatch.bat batch not found
) else (
    echo mybatch.bat is running %date% %time%
    timeout /T 10 /NOBREAK >NUL 2>&1
    goto :testMybatch
)
```

**2nd**. Otherwise, check if [`wmic` Windows Management Instrumentation command](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) output could help

```
wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get /value
```

Then you could detect `mybatch.bat` in its output narrowed to

```
wmic process where "name='cmd.exe'" get CommandLine, ProcessID
```

Note that `wmic` could return some [`Win32_Process` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx) properties, particularly `CommandLine`, **empty** if a particular process was launched under another user account or elevated (run as administrator). 

Elevated `wmic` returns all properties in full.

Answer (score 0):

What you say happens by default.

To test, crate a new .bat file (let's say 1.bat) and put in it

calc

mspaint

Save and run it.
Calculator will start. You will notice that Paitbrush will launch only when you have closed calculator.

Comment: You have misunderstood my question. The batch file I need to check if it running is run outside/before the batch file I need to write.