# Killing two process automatically after closing one program manually

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that starts two programs :

```dos
@echo off
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.lnk"
```

Now when i close program `"Kodi"`, i want that it close automatically first the task `"openvpn-gui.exe"` and then `"openvpn.exe"`

Thank you !

Comment: Related: [How to wait for a process to terminate to execute another process in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8185270/3439404).

Comment: thank you but it doesnt help me...

Comment: It's dirty way but try to write a batch script that kills both processes.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but give a try :

```dos
@echo off
Title Killing two process automatically after closing one program manually
set "RunningProcess=Kodi.exe"
set "Process2Kill=openvpn-gui.exe openvpn.exe"
tasklist /fi "imagename eq %RunningProcess%" /nh |find /i /c "%RunningProcess%"|findstr "^1$" >nul 
If "%Errorlevel%" EQU "1" (
    For %%a in (%Process2Kill%) do Call :KillProcess "%%a"
) else (
    echo %RunningProcess% is still running 
)
pause & exit

:KillProcess
Taskkill /f /im "%~1">nul 2>&1
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```dos
start "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn-gui.exe"
start "" "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe"
start "" /WAIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Kodi\Kodi.exe"
taskkill /IM "openvpn.exe"
taskkill /IM "openvpn-gui.exe"
```