# Batch - Resolve relative path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, relative-path

My batch scripts are located in the following directory:

```
\\test\public\windows\scripts\32\test.bat
```

I'm trying to get the path of this folder: \test\public\windows\logs
I've tried using `%~dp0` in order to get the path of the script, and i've tried:

```
SET REL_PATH=..\..\
```

The thing is that it's not showing me this folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET REL_PATH=..\..\
```

path points to the path according to you, to verify where it is taking from, please make a

```
echo %CD%
```

it will tell you the path the system is looking at.

then set the relative path from `%CD%` to the path of your script.

Please comment if you get stuck after doing this.

**For example**:

```
echo %CD%
```

gives `C:\windows\system32`

and you want to execute batch file at `c:\test\public\windows\scripts\32\test.bat`

you will need to do

```
SET REL_PATH=%CD%\..\..\test\public\windows\scripts\32\
```

To move to this path do a:

```
cd /d %REL_PATH%
```

To solve UNC path do PUSHD and POPD:

```
@echo off
pushd \\test\public\windows\scripts\32\

REM do your work
call test.bat

popd
```

Reference: [How to run batch file from network share without "UNC path are not supported" message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013941/how-to-run-batch-file-from-network-share-without-unc-path-are-not-supported-me)

Comment: The path is `c:\windows`, the variable `REL_PATH` is not giving me anything

Comment: Is it happening because i'm using `UNC` paths ?

Comment: from what i understand, your batch file is in a shared network drive and you want to execute it from your machine... is that correct?

Comment: Maybe you just need to get your UNC path mapped as a normal path. Maybe via `NET USE` or `MKLINK`. When that is done, path manipulation may be much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PUSHD` command when working with network drives. This will assign an unused drive letter to the UNC path so you can navigate it like normal. Then you can use `POPD` to release it.

For example:

```
@ECHO OFF

PUSHD "\\test\public\windows\scripts\32"

REM This will be \\test\public\windows
DIR ".\..\..\"

POPD
```