# Use of pushd and popd command with UNC path

Tags: batch-file

I am running the following batch file to run a stored package in `SQL` and I am getting a `UNC Paths are not supported` error. If I run it on the server it runs correctly. If I share it with other users it does not. I do not want to create a map drive. I've been reading about `pushd` command and it may be an option, but not sure how it works. Can someone guide me?

> ```
> "\\Server\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "\\Sever\c$\Packages\Unapplied and Patient Balances.dtsx"
> ```

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013941/how-to-run-batch-file-from-network-share-without-unc-path-are-not-supported-me)

Comment: Read this: [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pushd` as a quick version of `net use` if you will.
As you already observed UNC paths are not supported and so you have to work around. The command `pushd \\Server\Path\` will create a network drive on the machine it is running on like `Z:\` , automatically switch to it (like `cd /d Z:\`) and pushing the path on a stack (relevant for later).

You can then use this to access the server directories:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
pushd \\Server\c$
"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "Packages\Unapplied and Patient Balances.dtsx"
popd
```

Should do the trick.

The command `popd` is used to
1) delete the network drive and
2) pop the directory from the path

So you could actually could first push all the server paths you need (up to ~20 based on your file system) and in a loop execute the same thing for each path and execute popd to go to the next stored path.

When adding a `pause` before the `popd` and looking into the explorer, you can see the drive connected.

**NOTE:** This will only work if at least one drive letter is still unused as it is needed for temporary mapping!

**Edit:** Added `pushd "%~dp0"` to get rid of a warning mentioned in the comments. `%dp0` stands for the **d**rive and **p**ath of the **0**th batch-file argument that is always the batch-file itself. The `~` removes potential surrounding quotes.

**Edit2:** I started my Windows 7 VM to test this on my own. I wrote an .exe-file that only purpose it is to execute a batch-file that simply will create a file on the Desktop with the current time. I have no server so I could not test it to 100% but when trying to run it from the VM using `pushd \\localhost\c$` it worked fine... I tried to establish a connection from the host machine, but could not get it to work that way nor the other. Have you tried just running a batch-file that you create on the server? Something like:

```
%time%>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\myFile.txt"
```

Just to test the connection?

Feel free to ask if something is not clear!

Comment: I did exactly what you said and paused it and can see that a drive letter y is created but still get UNC paths are not supported.

Comment: Have a look at the code in my answer. Notice that I have deleted the parts of the paths that were causing the issue: `\\Server\c$`. If that does not solve the issue, are there any other messages?

Comment: '\\ServerName\C$\BatFile                                                                           CMD.exe was started with the above path as the current directory. UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to windows directory.   C:\Winddows>pushd \\servername\c$  Y:\>"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "Packages\ Unapplied and Patient Balances.dtsx"
Y:\popd

Comment: This is what it says when I pause it

Comment: Has the thing you wanted it to do work? As there was nothing that said `could not find path specified` it should have. In the post elzooilogico linked as comment it read that you could add `pushd %dp0` to get rid of the warning. I will edit that.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't run the .bat file to create the report. It works perfect on the server with pushd \\ServerName\c$
"Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /f "Packages\Unapplied and Patient Balances.dtsx"
popd

Comment: Do you probably have to grant administrative permissions to execute it? Or run the batch as Admin

Comment: Did it work or didnt it? I am still learning batch and I am eager to know what the problem is/was...

Comment: When I am home I will try something... We will get there!

Comment: @JohnMolina So after nearly one hour of testing I made the edit above... Not really proud of it :/