# How to delete everything inside a notwork folder

Tags: batch-file, networking, cmd, delete-file

I would like to delete everything inside a folder on a network drive, but not the folder itself. It's school drive, therefore I can't delete the folder and replace it. If I try to delete the folder, it will look like i deleted it, until I restart my pc. I need to have access to the folder afterwards, and a restart in between is just too inconvenient.

Things I've tried:

```
cd \\LOCATION
rd . /q /s
```

However this error occurs

```
CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.
```

I hope I explained this well enough, if there was something you didn't understand then just write, then I'll try to clarify.

Comment: You have to use pushd and popd, [see](https://superuser.com/questions/282963/browse-an-unc-path-using-windows-cmd-without-mapping-it-to-a-network-drive)

Comment: You have to use pushd and popd [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996943/use-of-pushd-and-popd-command-with-unc-path)

Comment: The process can not access the file as it is used by another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file and loop through every folder inside the folder you want to keep. Consider you have `\\LOCATION\Folder\folder2` then `folder3` etc. then this will remove all folders from within `\\LOCATION\Folder` but keep `Folder`:

```
set "myunc=\\LOCATION\Folder" 
pushd "%myunc%" && (
    for /d %%i in (*) do rmdir "%%i" /q /s 
    popd
)
```

`Set` sets a variable name of `myfunc` with a value which in this case is your path.

`For /d` is a loop that goes through each directory inside your `%myunc%` path and then simply do a `rd` on each.

`Pushd` allows you to pretty much `cd` to a network UNC path. `pushd` will create a temp drive letter for the UNC path. So it is almost like you doing `net use X: \\servername\path`

`popd` will then just remove the temp drive letter for you.

Open `cmd.exe` and type `pushd /?` and `popd /?`

To learn more on batch commands, from `cmd.exe` do `help` which will list all cmd commands, for each command you can run the `/?` switch to learn more about it.

Comment: Perfect. This worked fantastically. Could I get you to explain what the different things do? Because I dont understand much of it....

Comment: Added explanation to the Answer.

Comment: A single `rd . /s /q 2>nul` after the `pushd` would do the job. Besides that your FOR loop will not remove files in the root directory.

Comment: @sst the reason I use `rmdir "%%i"` is so the user could understands how this loop works.. I could have also elimiated the loop entirely, but I didn't. Also, OP specifies removing directory, not files, if he specified files I would have added it.

Comment: Fair enough. It seems that we have disagreement on interpreting things. That's what "delete everything inside..." means to me: to delete everything inside.

Comment: @sst yes, I get what you are saying, at a glance it seems like everything, but then he says deleting the folder, so seems he simply has a folder in that folder that he wants to delete, especially considering the fact that he used the `rd` command in his example. By the way, not disagreement in my view, just a discussion :)

Comment: Oh well, it was me not expressing myself correctly. I do/did need to remove all the folders as well. Gerhard Barnard's solution works like a charm. I havn't tried and properly will not try, the option you came with, sorry sst. But you know, no need to fix something that works.

Comment: @error40, You are free to try anything you see fit, nothing is personal here. It doesn't matter for any of us which method the reader chooses at the end, It's not a competition. Of course for your own good you should fully understand the implications of each method before using them. `rd . /s /q 2>nul` will remove everything inside the folder including all files and folders while keeping the root folder, Gerhard's method will remove all directories inside, but not the files inside the root folder. So that's up to you to decide which one fits your needs. That's all about it.

Comment: @sst I dont know if im understanding you right. Gerhards script removes everything inside \\network_location\folder_I_want_to_keep\folder_and_files_I_dont_want_to_delete after the scrip i have \\network_location\folder_I_want_to_keep\
I dont know if I misunderstood you

Answer (score -1):

Open the Start Menu and in the text box, type `cmd.exe` and hit Enter (or open the command prompt using your preferred method)
Switch to the network drive by typing `Z:` (where Z is the letter of the network drive)

Change to the parent directory of the directory you're trying to delete using `cd path\to\parent\directory`
Delete the directory using `rmdir /S giantdir` 
For example, if you want to delete the directory `O:\MG\WTF\BBQ\SOMANYFILES:`

`C:\Documents And Settings\Me> O:`

`O:> cd MG\WTF\BBQ`

`O:\MG\WTF\BBQ> rmdir /S SOMANYFILES`
Or now that I think about it, I think you could just do

`C:\Documents And Settings\Me> O:`

`O:> rmdir /S MG\WTF\BBQ\SOMANYFILES`
but you would miss out on the chance to see Windows spell out OMGWTFBBQ in terminal font ;-)

By the way, rmdir (or del) does not move things to the Recycle Bin, it just deletes them, 
so be careful not to delete things you don't really want to.