# Batch - Trying to read a text file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make a batch file that will read a text file (Net.txt) to pull a datapath from it. Assign it to a variable then empty a file from a nearby location.

Net.txt looks like

```
 SharedPath=C:\Program\2017\
 SharedUNC=C:\Program\2017\
```

Then find the directory and delete files with a specific extension.

```
cd %variable%\OPTION\trash
DEL *.xxx
```

This works great locally when everything is on C: but I don't think batch/cmd supports UNC paths. Is there a better language to use?

Comment: Might still be possible with batch-file: [How to run batch file from network share without “UNC path are not supported” message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9013941/2745495)

Answer (score 1):

To read a file line by line, use a `for /f` loop.
The following code assumes `net.txt` to be exactly as shown in your question and will delete the files in both the SharedPath and the SharedUNC (should they differ; if they are the same, `del` will spit an error for the second one (which you can suppress with `2>nul`))

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in (net.txt) do del "%%aOPTION\trash\*.xxx"
```

If that is not what you want, please describe your problem in more detail.