# UNC Paths are not supported

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to copy a file to a folder using the following batch script

```
echo xcopy \\path1\file.txt \\path2\backup
```

However, I get the following error:

> UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to the windows directory.

Is there a simple solution for this?

Comment: Try mounting the unc path to a network drive using net use: `net use x: \\path1` and `net use y: \\path2\backup` and then run `xcopy x:\file.txt y:\ `

Comment: Can this be done without admin rights?

Comment: No, I think you have to have admin rights

Comment: Is there an option without admin rights?

Comment: use `robocopy` instead, `xcopy` is deprecated.

Comment: I get the same error with robocopy

Comment: Are you wanting to copy single files? or entire folders?

Comment: single file only

Comment: The message isn't due to the source or destination paths, it is due to running the batch file from a UNC path. Check out [How to run batch file from network share without “UNC path are not supported” message?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9013941/2441).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Single file copying, simply use `copy`

```
copy /Y \\path1\file.txt \\path2\backup
```

Other ways to create a network share:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('net use * \\server1\folder\') do set src=%%i & goto :continue
:continue
for /f "tokens=2" %i in ('net use * \\server2\backup\') do set dest=%%i & goto :cp
:cp
copy %src%\file.txt %dest% /Y
net use /d %src%
net use /d %dest%
```

The above will only work if you have credentials setup already.. if not, you can do it as:

```
net use \\server1\IPC$ /user:username password
```

Comment: Anytime mate! :)