# batch file: how to check if %~dp0 is a UNC network path?

Tags: batch-file, unc

I have seen [How to run batch file from network share without "UNC path are not supported" message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013941/how-to-run-batch-file-from-network-share-without-unc-path-are-not-supported-me) - and the `pushd %~dp0` to mount the network path as a drive, and `popd` to unmount the drive, seems to work for me.

I'd just like to make the batch script capable of detecting whether the location the script is started from is a local, or a network/UNC path. How could I do that? I'd guess, one could check if the first two characters in the path are backslashes `\\`, but I have no idea how to do it in batch.

So, as somewhat of a pseudocode, I'd need something like:

```vb
call :IsUncPath %~dp0 is_unc_path

if %is_unc_path% == 1 (
  echo "Mounting UNC path as local drive"
  REM @pushd %~dp0
)

echo "Script does whatever here..."

if %is_unc_path% == 1 (
  echo "Unmounting local drive for UNC path"
  REM @popd
)

pause
:: "force execution to quit at the end of the "main" logic" http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-7-functions.html
EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%

:IsUncPath
echo The value of parameter 1 is %~1
:: NB: there must not be spaces around the assignment!
set "%~2=1"
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: Well, why do you want to do that? you could do `pushd`/`popd` anyway for all paths since local paths are kept unchanged and remote paths are mounted to a local drive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the errorlevel of `net use <drive letter>`.

```
call :isUncPath C:
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo C: is on UNC
exit /b

:IsUncPath
::: param1 - drive letter with colon, ex Y:
::: @return exitcode 0 - drive is network mapped
net use %~1 >nul 2>&1
EXIT /B %errorlevel%
```

Comment: Many thanks, that looks good! However, I don't really know how to read the return error code from a batch function - would you mind how I would read the return error status, and put it into a variable? (and what value should I check for, to determine this is indeed a network path? is it `returncode != 0`?)

Comment: @sdbbs I edited my answer to show the use of an errorlevel

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
@echo off
call :chkunc
if %errorlevel% equ 0 echo "%~dp0" is on UNC 
:: rest of your script
exit /b
:chkunc
set "testpath=%~dp0"
if "%testpath:~0,2%"=="\\" exit /b 0
exit /b 1
```

Comment: please test before posting.

Comment: I'm running from mobile now, why doesn't it work? UNC Paths always start with \\.

Comment: I have edited the code. I saw `if errorlevel` syntax at `if /?`.