# Delay Code to start the exe file

Tags: batch-file

I have this bat file to just kill and start the file, but I need a delay.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM "file.exe"
(what is the code to delay 1 minute before executing the code below?)
start /d "path" file.exe
```

Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ping` as @Krister suggested

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 60
```

of if you are using Vista and above you can use the much easier `timeout`

```
timeout /t 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `ping` command to achive this, you could ping an invalid host and set the timeout for the command to your desired delay.

```
@echo off
ping 1.2.3.4 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL
# this command will be run after 60000ms
echo 'running';
pause
```