# Moving Files Continuously with a Batch Script

Tags: loops, batch-file, jpeg

I'm trying to create a .bat file to continuously move new images to a folder to archive them. So far I have figured out how to get the images to move between folders without prompting to be overwritten but getting the action to loop has been tricky for me.

## Script to move files between folders

```
@echo off
echo File Copy Started 
xcopy /s /Y "Source" "Destination" 
echo File Copy Completed 
pause
```

Does anyone have any ideas to get this script to loop continuously? I was thinking of using something such as

```
IF EXIST .jpeg (an image)
then run the script to move the files 

ELSE 
Pause
```

?? I'm Just not sure how to start writing this. Any feed back would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/269126), might give you some ideas and provide part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
@echo off
:LOOP
echo File Copy Started 
xcopy /s /Y "Source" "Destination" 
echo File Copy Completed
goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfect. I can't believe I didn't think to loop it like that.  : )

Comment: No worries, sometimes the simplest solutions are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the AT command or the Windows Scheduler to run the task on a continuous basis