# Scheduled task: need to insert 10 second pauses between commands

Tags: task

I'm creating a scheduled task to restart the same three services on different servers. I need the commands to add 10 second pauses between each stop/start.

ex:

sc \Server1 stop "Service1"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server1 start "Service1"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server1 stop "Service2"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server1 start "Service2"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server2 stop "Service1"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server2 start "Service1"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server2 stop "Service2"

-- 10 second pause

sc \Server2 start "Service2"

Comment: is this what you mean? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos

Comment: By the way, specifying the language/environment (as a tag) would be lovely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `sleep 10`.