# How to copy each file at a time to destination folder?

Tags: batch-file

In my source folder i have 10 files. For every 10 mins i want to copy one file to destination folder. How can we do it using bat file? I don't want to copy multiple files at a time.

Comment: Yes, you can do this with a batch file. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
copy "%%a" "c:\target folder\"
timeout /t 600
)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much i have found the answer. These command works cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (complete and modify) something like that:

```
for %%f in (set-of-files) do (
    copy %%f dest-path
    ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul
)
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos) explains the use of `ping` to make a pause of x ms.

Answer (score -1):

```
For each file in directory
    Copy that file
    Wait 10 minutes
```

Comment: I told an example of 10 files. Actually i have to copy 1000 files.