# Batch File to Send Multiple Commands to a Specific Program Already Open

Tags: batch-file, command, port, prompt, modem

I have a command line application called "terminal.exe" which provides a simple way to communicate with a modem port attached to the PC. [image: Terminal Interface]

To access the first device I would simply enter "1" and then I can send AT commands directly to the modem port.

Now, how would I write a batch file to launch "terminal.exe", then enter "1" into the terminal application and then send an AT command such as "at+cfun=1"?

I have attempted to do the following which seems to throw terminal.exe into an infinite loop where it keeps reloading the startup list of modems until I have to terminate the process with "ctr+c":

```
(echo 1 & echo at+cfun=1) | terminal
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _I would simply enter "1" and then I can send AT commands_: `1` or `1<Enter>`? If no `<Enter>`, then try `echo 1at+cfun=1|terminal`. Note no `|` surrounding spaces.

Comment: And no `&` surrounding spaces if `<Enter>` required: `(echo 1&echo at+cfun=1)|terminal`

Comment: Removing the spaces fixed the infinite loop, however, the second command does not go through. That is, once I'm connected to the COM Port the application stops responding.

Comment: Is there a way to add a pause before sending the second command?

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1672349/3439404)

Comment: But how would that be incorporated with '(echo 1&echo at+cfun=1)|terminal' ? I am only guessing that a pause could fix this issue. Is it possible perhaps to access an application ones it's already running?

Comment: to insert a pause of right one second, use `(echo 1&ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000>nul&echo at+cfun=1)|terminal` however not sure whether the `>` redirector should be escaped as follows: `ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 3000^>nul`