# Difference between Sleep and Timeout?

Tags: batch-file, timeout, sleep

So I have created a text adventure batch game, but after testing it on my home computer, none of the sleep commands work. My home PC is running Win 8.1 and the Laptop used to creating the game is running Win7. I don't know if this is the reason why the 'Sleep' function don't work..

But could anyone tell me the difference between `sleep` and `timeout` ? And why isn't the sleep commands working anymore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`Sleep`](http://ss64.com/vb/sleep.html) is a Windows Scripting Host command (like JScript or VBScript).  It's not really a cmd-interpreted batch thing.

[`Timeout`](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) is like a [`pause`](http://ss64.com/nt/pause.html) that auto continues after a specified time or on keypress (unless the `/nobreak` switch is used).

There's also [`waitfor`](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html), which pauses for X seconds or until a signal is received from another computer or window.

`timeout` and `waitfor` are included with Windows 7 and newer.  For compatibility with earlier versions of Windows, traditionally, `ping` is used to simulate a pause like this:

```
ping -n 6 0.0.0.0 >NUL
```

... will pause for 5 seconds.  (`-n 6` means ping 6 times.  The first ping response is instant, so N+1 is needed to pause N seconds.)

Some people also use [`choice /t`](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) to pause.  See the [How to sleep for 5 seconds in Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/) related page if you'd like.  There may be a reference to a utility or resource kit there you've installed that makes Sleep work on your Win 7 laptop, which has not been installed on your 8.1 desktop.

Comment: That works, but now I have a very annoying "wating for 3...2...1... seconds, press CTRL+C to quit" message showing each time I use the command. Any way to hide the "debug message"?

Comment: Just redirect the output: `timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul`

Comment: `Timeout` seems to be also available in some older Windows versions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc754891(v=ws.11)