# how to end a program after a predetermined set of time (in minutes) as a .bat file

Tags: batch-file

I want to build a simple .bat file that after a predetermined set of time (like an hour or so) it will kill a program once's it's started. So say I run the batch file and after 1 hour or so it will kill another program (say firefox)

Comment: Do you mean that the other program will be killed, or that the batch program will be killed?

Comment: Which operating system (Windows is implied by the '.bat' extension, but not explicit). Can you tell us (or, better yet, show us) what you've tried already?

Comment: @kdopen I wasn't sure, so I posted an answer that should work on either DOS or Windows. :b

Answer (score 0):

To make the batch execution pause, you can use a kludge as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos) The 3600 corresponds to 3600 seconds, or one hour.

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3600 > nul
```

To kill firefox, you can add a command such as

```
taskkill /im firefox.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

[dr_andonuts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28356901/4533527) has a standard way or practice I observe many do

An alternative is

batchfile content:

> timeout 3600
>
> taskkill /f /im firefox.exe