# timer shorter than a second[BATCH]

Tags: batch-file, timer

I can do this:

timeout /t 1 /nobreak

But what I can't do is this:

timeout /t 0.5 /nobreak

All I want is to set the wait time shorter than a second.
Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sleep for 5 seconds in Windows's Command Prompt? (or DOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos)

Comment: No, you can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `sleep`:

```
sleep -m 500
```

Which would sleep for half a second.