# Run a batch file 5 minutes after startup in Windows Xp

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

I want to execute a .bat file 5 minutes after windows starts up. Unfortunately, windows task scheduler doesn't offer anything of the sort, only execute something right on start up. However, I need something to be 5 minutes after startup.

.bat file doesn't do much, just calls one separate .cmd file and passes a parameter. I've tried:

```
timeout /t 300 /nobreak
"C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\sikuli\runIDE.cmd" -r "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\sikuli\SikuliXmlTestRunner.sikuli"
```

However, the runIDE.cmd gets called right away, regardless of the timeout.

Comment: `schtasks /create /?` lists a `/delay` parameter. Also in the GUI with [Trigger] there is a delay-option.

Comment: @Stephan, I think XP doesn't have it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sleep for 5 seconds in Windows's Command Prompt? (or DOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos)

Comment: Do you have `timeout.exe` installed? [It's not generic in Windows XP](http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give **wait(300)** command at the beginning in your **sikuli script** to achieve this.

Comment: add 1st line of your script  - wait(300)

Answer (score 2):

XP doesn't have `timeout` command, use `ping -n 300 localhost>nul` or `ping -n 1 -w 300000 localhost>nul`.