# How to use wait in MAKEFILE when I use it through NMAKE in windows

Tags: makefile, nmake

I'm not familiar with *MAKEFILE* and trying to figure out how to wait between **destroy** and **deploy** for 2 seconds.

It looks like *NMAKE* has very limited resource on internet and the one I found `sleep 2` throws **'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

> I'm working on *WINDOWS* not *LINUX*.

```
REGISTRY=registry.cengiz.dev
IMAGE=cengiz.geocode.host
TAG=latest

MARATHON=http://mesos.cengiz.dev/v2/apps/geocode
PAYLOAD=Marathon_geocode.json

.PHONY: deploy

push:
    docker push $(REGISTRY)/$(IMAGE):$(TAG)

destroy:push
    curl -X DELETE $(MARATHON)
    echo Waiting
    sleep 2

deploy:destroy
    curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" $(MARATHON) -d@$(PAYLOAD)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the `timeout` command:

```
timeout 3
```

Note that I intentionally wrote `3` to assure that two seconds passed (instead of `2`: the current second will pass and then another one). See more about it in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-5-seconds-in-windowss-command-prompt-or-dos#1672375).

Comment: I needed to add colon at the end to make it work like this  timeout 5:

Comment: For everyone that didn't see this question is for Windows: On unix use `sleep 3` to achieve the same effect