# How to run a PowerShell script before my .NET project is transfered into memory and built?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, msbuild

I already know how to run arbitrary PowerShell script before building starts.

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command &quot;&amp; {.\script.ps1 '$(SolutionDir)'}&quot;" />
  <Sleep Delay="3000"/>
</Target>
```

My problem is that the script I want to run modifies part of a `.cs` file. But this script above runs **after** the code was already copied into memory and when it builds, it uses the content of `.cs` file **before** it was modified.

Is there a way to start buidling process but run PowerShell script earlier, before my code is copied into memory?
You could say I want to run a preprocessor that will call an external executable before any compilation process even begins.

If not, is there a way to build the project twice in a row without having to click `Build` in my IDE twice? (dirty hack that would fix my issue)

Quick note about `<Sleep Delay="5000"/>`. Because my PowerShell script is starting a process that is asynchronous and very short I also added a `Delay` task I found posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213107

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeforeBuild` target happens after compilation happens, so your code will already be compiled by then... to achieve the desired functionality, you should try using `BeforeCompile` target:

```xml
<Target Name="BeforeCompile">
  <Exec Command="powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -command &quot;&amp; {.\script.ps1 '$(SolutionDir)'}&quot;" />
  <Sleep Delay="3000"/>
</Target>
```

See [this Microsoft Docs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-extend-the-visual-studio-build-process?view=vs-2019) for more info