# Can someone tell me, why this batch script isn't working?

Tags: batch-file, random, echo

```
@echo off
:start
SET /A number=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
echo %number%>number.txt
PING localhost -n 2 >NUL
goto start
```

It should generate a random number from 1-3. And it does. But the .txt file is just empty and in the console, I get the message: "Echo is turned off".

Can someone help me?

Comment: seems to work in my PC. And unrelated but [`timeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714) might be better than ping

Answer (score 2):

```
>number.txt echo %number%
```

A digit directly before a redirector redirects a logical device (0=stdin, 1=stdout, 2=stderr, others unassigned). The position of the redirection instruction is generally irrelevant; only at the end of the command by convention and historical usage.

Comment: no need to reverse the order, a space before `>` will help `echo %number% >number.txt`

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Not so. The space will be output to the file, but reversing the order will prevent the file having terminal spaces on the line.