# exit/close cmd launced from batch file that start another batch file

Tags: batch-file, exit

I use a batch file to create another batch file with some part extracted from a file, it create a long file.

I need to add only one an `exit` command in the end of file.

Actually the batch files created do not close after finish the work.

Code File to create another batch file:

```bat
 :: 'Create Batch File'
 @echo off
     (for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\list.csv") > do (
        echo PING -n %%~NXa localhost ^>NUL 2^>^&1
        echo/
        echo/
     )) > "D:\Programmi Installati\new.bat"
```

Actual result of new.bat (wrong):

```bat
PING -n 10 localhost >NUL 2>&1
exit

PING -n 15 localhost >NUL 2>&1
exit

PING -n 20 localhost >NUL 2>&1
exit

PING -n 25 localhost >NUL 2>&1
exit
```

Aspected result of `new.bat` (desired):

```bat
PING -n 10 localhost >NUL 2>&1


PING -n 15 localhost >NUL 2>&1


PING -n 20 localhost >NUL 2>&1


PING -n 25 localhost >NUL 2>&1
exit
```

Comment: It should be `do`  not `> do`.

Comment: Hi the bat file working well, the unique bug is how to add at the end of file generated exit . The batch file create another batch file with estraction and loop and working well, but i do not find a solution to add at the end (only at the end 1 times only) exit.

Comment: Where do you `echo` exit? Please provide just a piece of `list.csv` for us to be able to reproduce your problem. Edit your question to fix typo mentioned by Compo. Also, is it working if you put after the `for` loop `(echo exit)>>"D:\Programmi Installati\new.bat"`? Please provide us more information, but please do not comment it. Instead, edit your question.

Comment: @double-beep Your solution working well it's exactly the solution at my problem add 1 exit after the loop at the end of the batch file create (echo exit)>>"D:\Programmi Installati\new.bat" Thanks you solved my problem.

Comment: the `exit` is not the only bug in your code. What Compo said is also one. And don't use `ping` for delaying, it'll sleep for one less second than expected [How to sleep for 5 seconds in Windows's Command Prompt? (or DOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714), [How do I make a batch file wait / sleep for some seconds?](https://superuser.com/q/48231/241386)

Comment: @phuclv Thanks for suggestion i'll optimize the code of the script. can you add more info about this because i do not know this error "It should be do not > do", thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, except the typo in your code you have missed to `echo` `exit` in the end of your code block. Your code should look like the following after the fixes:

```bat
@rem 'Create Batch File'
@echo off

(for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("D:\Programmi Installati\list.csv") do (
    echo PING -n %%~NXa localhost ^>NUL 2^>^&1
    echo/
    echo/
))>"D:\Programmi Installati\new.bat"
echo exit >> "D:\Programmi Installati\new.bat"
```