# Why does ping ::1 -n 3 only wait 2 seconds?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping

I am creating a wait program using batch, but when I try to insert the 3 seconds delay using ping :

```
ping ::1 -n 3 >nul 2>nul
```

Only waits 2 seconds. Why does this happen?

Comment: Keep in mind, ping is not a timer. `-n` is number of replies required. Your first ping is on execution, 1 second to the second ping, 1 second to the last ping. making it two seconds. Why not instead use `timeout 3 /nobreak >nul 2>&1`

Comment: note that ping is not a good way for delaying. There are many better tools [How to sleep for five seconds in a batch file/cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/995714)

Comment: @phuclv Yes, I know, but I was just experimenting. Doesn't hurt to find out new things :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it makes its first `ping` without a delay (on execution). three `ping`s means 2 delays. If you like to have a delay of 3 seconds, you need to ping 4 times.

Comment: Or use something that actually causes a delay by design, instead of a networking test program.