# How to wait/sleep/delay in Linux terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, pause

This is similar to what was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672338/how-to-sleep-for-five-seconds-in-a-batch-file-cmd/20469610#20469610) but most of the answers were for Windows batch file. So, I decided to share for Ubuntu (20.04) Linux. Other Linux distros users are welcome to share as well.

I wanted to run a particular command multiple times from the terminal and needed it to pause for a bit before running again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my command

`$ for i in {0..5};do echo 1; sleep 10; done`

This prints `1` 6 times (counter ends in the last number in range in command line), but waits for `10 secs` after each print action.

Notice the `sleep` command.

`pause` and `timeout` don't work