# How to loop a command continually in batch files

Tags: loops, batch-file

As the title says what parameters would you use in a batch file to continually execute a command e.g.

start notepad
loop

Comment: Why would you want to?v (perhaps see here: http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an infinite loop in Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487473/how-to-create-an-infinite-loop-in-windows-batch-file)

Answer (score 6):

Another option in a single line (which will also work from the command line):

```
for /l %x in (1,0,2) do (start /wait notepad)
```

If you're using that in a batch file, use

```
for /l %%x in (1,0,2) do (start /wait notepad)
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks for this. It works perfectly. Could you explain the syntax to make the answer even better ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `goto`:

```
:loop
start /wait notepad
goto loop
```

Note that I have used `start /wait` here. If you don't do that, your batch file won't wait for `notepad` to exit, and you'll start a zillion notepads and probably eventually crash.

Comment: Sorry didnt work, loaded notepad, batch stopped, so I quite notepad and it close the batch

Comment: My apologies, I had the label syntax backwards. A label is `:loop` as now shown above (I edited my answer).

Comment: Thats it, should of spotted the typo myself!

Comment: Can you make it wait 5 seconds and then loop?

Comment: @James: There are several techniques for doing that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348849/pause-in-batch-file.